# Replace underscores with spaces and capitalize words

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to create a way to convert text with lowercase letters and underscores into text without underscores and the first letter of each word is capitalized.

ex;

```
options_page = Options Page
```

At this page: [How to make first character uppercase of all words in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478227/how-to-make-first-character-uppercase-of-all-words-in-javascript)

I found this regex:

```
key = key.replace(/(?:_| |\b)(\w)/g, function(key, p1) { return p1.toUpperCase()});
```

This does everything except replace the underscores with spaces. I have not really tried anything because I am not that familiar with regexpressions.

How can I adjust this regex so it replaces underscores with spaces?

Comment: For those who are using lodash, there is `startCase` function for that

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
function humanize(str) {
  var i, frags = str.split('_');
  for (i=0; i<frags.length; i++) {
    frags[i] = frags[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + frags[i].slice(1);
  }
  return frags.join(' ');
}


console.log(humanize('humpdey_dumpdey'));
// > Humpdey Dumpdey
```

**repl**

http://repl.it/OnE

**Fiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/nf4NG/

**jsPerf**:

**Most test data**: http://jsperf.com/string-transformations

**All versions plus _.str**: http://jsperf.com/string-transformations/3

Comment: I'm with you concerning code size but according to my [tests](http://jsperf.com/string-transformations) `str.split` is way faster in most browsers.

Comment: Code size is [131](http://bit.ly/1hkQNOl) vs [111](http://bit.ly/1g6IU9O) bytes when uglified and defined as `function humanize`.

Comment: Interesting result! I'll need to revise my practices.

Comment: 20 times faster. Nice.

Comment: Instantly readable/understandable code, and faster than regex. Who would have thought it possible?

Comment: If you also need ALL CAPS => All Caps add this as the first thing in your for loop:
`frags[i] = frags[i].toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 15):

Since Lodash 3.1.0, there's a `_.startCase([string=''])` method that transforms any case into capitalized words (start case):

```
_.startCase('hello_world'); // returns 'Hello World'
_.startCase('hello-world'); // returns 'Hello World'
_.startCase('hello world'); // returns 'Hello World'
```

There are other useful methods in the String section of Lodash. Read the documentation [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#startCase).

Comment: sidenote: if you want to import only this one function instead of the entire library in react you can use import startCase from 'lodash/startCase' at the top of your file instead of importing the entire library if you're only using it for this one thing.

Answer (score 8):

These are two different tasks, so two different regexes is the best solution:

```
key = key.replace(/_/g, ' ').replace(/(?: |\b)(\w)/g, function(key) { return key.toUpperCase()});
```

To ensure even all capital words is processed. You can add `.toLowerCase()` before the very first `.replace`:

```js
console.log('TESTING_WORD'.toLowerCase().replace(/_/g, ' ')
.replace(/(?: |\b)(\w)/g, function(key, p1) {
    return key.toUpperCase();    
}));
```

Comment: You can remove the underscore from the second regexp, since they've all been removed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, as is, it is producing the same results as before; contact_details = ContactDetails; It is not putting the space in there.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that the second regex also removes spaces. I've edited the code to change that functionality. Now it works as intended, you can check out [here](http://repl.it/Omi).

Comment: To make it better you can add `key.toLowerCase()` before the very first `key.replace` 
to ensure even all capital words is processed.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative:

```js
camel = "options_page".replace(/(^|_)(\w)/g, function ($0, $1, $2) {
  return ($1 && ' ') + $2.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(camel);
```

The regular expression:

```
(^|_)   beginning of the input OR "_" ($1)
(\w)    a word character (short for [a-zA-Z0-9_]) ($2)
g       all occurrences (global)
```

More about regular expressions : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add .`replace('_',' ')`

Like this

```
function toCamel(string){
  return string.replace(/(?:_| |\b)(\w)/g, function($1){return $1.toUpperCase().replace('_',' ');});
}
```

Comment: hi, how to make all is in Capital Letter? maybe you make two version, 1 is above and the other one is all in caps.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
var str = 'Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet,_consectetur____adipiscing_elit.'
str = str.replace(/_{1,}/g,' ').replace(/(\s{1,}|\b)(\w)/g, function(m, space, letter)
{
  return space + letter.toUpperCase();
})

console.log(str);
```