# avoiding newline from split()?

Tags: javascript

I have a list in a string, as below (from a `<textarea>` element with `id=list`):

```
q1

q2
q3


q4
```

JavaScript:

```
var TA = document.getElementById("list").value; 
lines = TA.split("\r\n");
```

I want `lines` variable to have the values `q1,q2,q3,q4`,
but the result is `q1,,q2,q3,,,q4` (note the empty items)

I want to avoid the blank strings in the result array - how can I do that?

Comment: Please format your question in a way that makes it readable ... I tried to interpret what you meant but failed.

Comment: @kobi : thaks for the alignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove empty elements from the array after splitting it. See

[Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks by using following jQuery code it works wonderfully var arr = [1,2,,3,,3,,,0,,,4,,4,,5,,6,,,,];

arr = $.grep(arr,function(n,i){
    return(n);
});

arr // [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: @kiran - note that the function is removing falsy values from the array - `0` was also removed!

Comment: @kobi : Thaks i didnt noticed that, i wan to retain 0 also

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this, which should also take care of other formats of new lines (for example, only `\n`):

```
var lines = TA.split(/[\r\n]+/);
```

Or, to remove blank lines and spaces before/after your tokens (this one will only match the `\r\n` format, but you can use `[\r\n]` instead):

```
var lines = TA.split(/\s*\r\n\s*/);
```

---

Alternatively, you can match the lines instead of splitting the newlines:

```
var lines = TA.match(/.+/g);
```

`.` doesn't match new lines, so `.+` is really matching a whole line, and skips empty lines. This will also skip empty tokens at the beginning or end of the array (as in `\n\n a \n b`), while `split` still creates empty elements.

Comment: i want to match newlines, but except those new lines that are empty

Comment: @kiran - Try them, they should all work. If you're talking about the last option - that one is the best of the three! You *don't* want to match newlines at all - you want to match the **lines** `:)`

Comment: Thanks, last one works wondefully in mozilla, but in IE its not working, i tested with IE7

Comment: what change shld i made to wrk in IE

Comment: @Kiran - Weird, it is very basic and should. It's working for me in IE7 and even in IE6 (assuming `TA.value` is a string): http://jsbin.com/omaqi4 . Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Replace multiple \r\n by one before splitting

```
TA.replace(/(\r\n)+/g, "\r\n").split("\r\n")
```

Comment: @steefan : it cant be all the case, possibly there can be double empty lines or triplr empty lines.

Comment: The regexp works for any number of newlines (+ stand for one or more). So double, tripple, or 100 empty lines, the regexp will replace them by one newline.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var lines = TA.split(/[\r\n]{1,}/g);`