# Replace/remove empty entries in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, replace

I have this Array: `[home, info, mail,,,, something, stuff, other]`

But I want to remove or replace the `,,` with `,`

I tried: `allIDs.replace(",,", ",");` But it doesn't seem to work with Arrays

The reason there are empty entries is this:

```
$(document).find('DIV').each(function(){
    allIDs.push(this.id); })
```

I'm indexing all DIV's ID names, to check if there are duplicates and then rename the currently generated DIV ID..

Alternatively I'd like to `find()` only the DIV's that have an ID defined..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `id` gathering to this...

```
var allIDs = $(document).find('DIV')
                        .map(function(){ return this.id || undefined })
                        .toArray();
```

If there's no ID on the `DIV`, `undefined` will be returned, and nothing will be added to the resulting Array.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$('div[id]')` instead. It will select all `div` elements with `id` attribute defined.

Answer (score 2):

This works really well:

```
theArray = theArray.filter(function(e) { return e; });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to remove the empty values from the Array, not replace the `,,` with `,` i suppose.

Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get only `div`s with IDs defined:

```
$(document).find('div[id]').each(function(){
    allIDs.push(this.id); });
});
```

But if you want to clean the array:

```
allIDs = clean_up(allIDs);

function clean_up(a){
    var b = []
    for(i in a) if(a[i] && a[i].length) a.push(a[i]);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can't just remove ',,,' in an array to solve the problem.

Do you mean the array ['home', 'info', '', '', '', '', 'mail', 'something', 'stuff', 'other']?

Suppose there is some empty string, and you want to remove them.

You can use a simple javascript function:

```
allIDs = ["home", "info", "", "", "", "", "mail", "something", "stuff", "other"];

remove_empty_str = function(arr) {
  new_array = [];
  for (ii = 0, len = arr.length; ii < len; ii++) {
    item = arr[ii];
    if (item !== "" || item !== null || item !== (void 0)) {
      new_array.push(item);
    }
  }
  return new_array;
};

newIDs = remove_empty_str(allIDs);

alert(newIDs);
```

I would think it's better practice to process the array before do any jQuery output.

You can also re-use remove_empty_str() in other apps too.