# how to remove null values from an array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

I want to remove `null` or empty elements from an array using `jquery`

```
var clientName= new Array();
clientName[0] = "jack";
clientName[1] = "";
clientName[2] = "john";
clientName[2] = "peter";
```

Please give some suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you asking for people to point you in the direction of loop statements and comparison operators?

Comment: `{}` is an object definition list, not an array definition list. Which would be `[]`.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Must be a typo, it would not be a valid object literal.

Comment: I tried to edit it to `[]`, but the OP insists it's `{}` :). The example code will throw a Syntax error.

Comment: The current edit looks OK. In the previous version: since JavaScript is a dynamic language it won't get upset if you create a new variable of type array, and then discard it by replacing it with a new variable type object. Besides that arrays are objects and object properties can be accessed using the array brackets.

Comment: @MihaiStancu That's true, but `var x = { 1, 2, 3 };` is invalid code. You have to define the keys too (you are free to try it in your console, I did). The current edit is fine though, even if it reaches the same goal as my edit.

Answer (score 22):

Use the jquery **grep** function, it'll identify array elements that pass criteria you define

```
arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function(n, i){
  return (n !== "" && n != null);
});
```

Comment: You cann add that to ie. ... return(n !== "" && n != null && n !== 0)...

Comment: +1 Much better with `!==`. `grep` is a good option by the way if one uses jQuery anyways.

Comment: @bažmegakapa thank you for reminding me implicitly about the difference between '!==' and '!=' :)

Comment: may be `return (n ? true: false)` is more efficient?

Answer (score 5):

There is no need in jQuery, use plain JavaScript (it is faster!):

```
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < clientname.length; i++) {
    if (clientname[i] !== "" && clientname[i] !== null) {
        newArray.push(clientname[i]);
    }
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Another simple solution for modern browsers (using Array [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method):

```
clientname.filter(function(value) {
    return value !== "" && value !== null;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Was thinking that since jQuery's `.map()` function relies on returning something *not* null / undefined, you can get away with just something like this:

```
var new_array = $.map(old_array, function (el) {
    return el !== '' ? el : null;
});
```

You still have to check for the empty string, but you really don't have to check for the null and undefined anymore, so that's one less complication in your logic.

Comment: From the manual: Within the function, `this` refers to the global (`window`) object. Also, you have to get rid of the `''`. The idea is good though.

Comment: @bažmegakapa ~ ah, good catch! Completely forgot about the empty string check, d'oh. If that's the case, this'll just reduce to any of the other answers here anyway.

Comment: Still +1, the idea is good. It's good that people don't have to check for `null` and `undefined`, because they seem to have enough problems with that, looking at the other answers :).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new empty array.
2. Go into a foreach loop and add items to new array if value is not equal to ''.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$.each(clientname, function(key, value) { 
  if (value === 'undefined' || value === '')
     clientname.splice(key,1);
});
```

Comment: This will remove `0` as well.

Comment: Yes @bažmegakapa, but the array doesn't seems to contain numeric values. I've made a fix.

Comment: Even worse :). `0 == ''`. And what about that `'undefined'`?

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```
var newarr=[];
for(var i=0; i<len(clientname);i++){

   if(clientname[i] !== "" && clientname[i] !== null){
    newarr.push(clientname[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: This will remove `0` as well.

Comment: Have you tried? `0 == ''` in Javascript.

Comment: Sorry, but is still the same. No matter if you use this in your own code, because it's you who has to fix it, but please don't spread it on the Internet. [Hint](http://zero.milosz.ca/).

Comment: I am not your code interpreter. Please create a jsFiddle demo or use your console to test your own code. It won't run.