# How to remove null values from array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove null values from a array.
For example

```
var data = [
    ["George L. Bunting", null, null, null],
    ["Marc G. Bunting", null, null, null],
    ["Suzanne F. Cohen", null, null, null],
    ["Rosalee  Davison", null, null, null],
    ["Richard  Davison", null, null, null],
    ["Marilynn K. Duker", null, null, null],
    ["Dale  McArdle", null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null]
]
```

I required to get like this

```
data = [
    ["George L. Bunting", null, null, null],
    ["Marc G. Bunting", null, null, null],
    ["Suzanne F. Cohen", null, null, null],
    ["Rosalee  Davison", null, null, null],
    ["Richard  Davison", null, null, null],
    ["Marilynn K. Duker", null, null, null],
    ["Dale  McArdle", null, null, null]
]
```

and remove space between words 'Dale  McArdle'-> 'Dale McArdle'?

```
$("input[id*=btnListGeneratorwithDetails]").click(function() {
    $("[id*=hdnfldSpreadSheetData]").val(JSON.stringify(handsontable.getData()));

    strEntityList = JSON.stringify(handsontable.getData());
    //alert(strEntityList);
});
```

Comment: You can find another duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745800/how-to-remove-null-values-from-an-array-using-jquery

Comment: That is a problem. A big one. Try and [ask again](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when you run into trouble.

Comment: Why jQuery? If it's jQuery, why did you not tag it as such? Also, please ask one question at a time. Anyway, where you stuck on this? Do you not know how to loop over the array? Do you not know how to access each element, and check if it's all nulls? Did you not know how to remove an unwanted element?

Comment: torazaburo - how to remove unwanted element [null, null, null, null] jquery or javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
var data = [
    ["George L. Bunting", null, null, null],
    ["Marc G. Bunting", null, null, null],
    ["Suzanne F. Cohen", null, null, null],
    ["Rosalee  Davison", null, null, null],
    ["Richard  Davison", null, null, null],
    ["Marilynn K. Duker", null, null, null],
    ["Dale  McArdle", null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null]
]
data = data.filter(function(entry) {
    return !entry.every(function(value) {
        return value === null;
    });
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: i'm not getting answer

Comment: @0143.NetUser SO doesn't support `console.log`. Try it your self instead.