# How to remove the null values from array result using jquery

Tags: jquery, linq

This is my linq query but here I am not getting null. In the result set in jquery code I am getting null

```
var Data = await (from Names in apiDbContext.name.AsNoTracking()
   .Where(a => a.IsActive == true) orderby NamesList.Name select NamesList)
   .ToListAsync();
```

Below is my screen shot where i am getting null in the data because of this null i am getting error

[image]

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null.

```js
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: remote_url,
      async: false,
      success: function(data) { 
    /* Near this data i am getting last record as null because of this 
       I am getting error as Cannot read property 'username' of null  */
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
          var title = val[Text];
        })
      })
```

Comment: You can filtered values in backend code.for example with linq
 array.Where(q=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(q))

Comment: var arr = ["",1,2,3,4,5,6,'123',33,'asd',"",'',1,''];
arr = arr.filter(function(value) {
    return value !== "" && value !== null;
});
console.log(arr); ... for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745800/how-to-remove-null-values-from-an-array-using-jquery

Comment: I had already tried this parth but still i am getting the same exception

Comment: To remove empty null or blank values from an array please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: var Data = await (from Names in apiDbContext.name.AsNoTracking().Where(a => a.IsActive == true)
                                         orderby NamesList.Name
                                         select NamesList).ToListAsync();   this is my linq query but here i am not getting null in the result set in jquery code i am getting null