# Javascript regex help to split a string into Days, Hours, Minutes ("s" or no "s")

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
var str = "2 Days, 2 Hours 10 Minutes";
```

if I :

```
str.split(/Days/);
```

I get:

```
["2 ", ", 2 Hours 10 Minutes"]
```

So I think I can use string.split to split out my string and get the "days", "hours" and "minutes" with this method.

However, what do I do when I sometimes have "s" or no "s", for example:

```
var str = "1 Day, 2 Hours 10 Minutes";
```

Here my string is "1 Day" not "2 Days" so I don't have the "s" on the "day" value. Is there a way to split a string on

```
Day(s)
Hour(s)
Minute(s)
```

Comment: How will it behave if there are 0 of something? Like `1 Day, 0 Hours 1 Minute` or `0 Days, 0 Hours, 0 Minutes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a Regular Expression to do the split, so simply place a question mark after the 's' to make it optional:

```
str.split(/Days?/);
```

You probably also want to make it case-insensitive by adding the `i` flag to the Regex:

```
str.split(/days?/i);
```

You could also do the whole thing with a single line using the `match` string method (instead of `split`) like this:

```
("2 Days, 3 hours, 5 minutes").match(/(\d+)\s*days?\,?\s*(\d+)\s*hours?\,?\s*(\d+)\s*minutes?/i)
```

That will return an array like this:

```
["2 Days, 3 hours, 5 minutes", "2", "3", "5"]
```

So the items in positions 1, 2 and 3 are the days, hours and minutes respectively.

To break that Regex down into english:

- (captured group, i.e. array item 1) 1 or more digits
- zero or more whitespace characters
- day
- optional s
- optional comma
- zero or more whitespace characters
  ... and repeat for hours and minutes.

Check the docs for regex matching on strings [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), and great docs on how to use regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: On a side note - I highly recommend checking out the MomentJS library if you're working with dates. http://momentjs.com

Comment: OMG, that library looks great.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
str.split(/Days?/);
str.split(/Hours?/);
str.split(/Minutes?/);
```

Comment: This provides three separate arrays none of which the OP is actually looking for.

Comment: From the example, it isn't quite clear if the OP wants anything except a way to split using an optional 's'

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to get the Days/Hours/Minutes into a single 3 element array and you can guarantee your inputs will always have a value (even if that value is 0), it might be simpler just to eradicate all non-numerics and non-spaces and then split on space and remove empty elements.

```
var result = new Array();
var tempstr = str.replace(/[^0-9\s]/g, ''); 
var arr = tempstr.split(' ');

for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i]) {
        result.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

*Note: Array cleaning loop appropriated from [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript).*