# JSON stringify and decode JS/PHP

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with sending an object in PHP. I stringify the object before sending it to the PHP file.

The PHP file then uses json_decode. But the decode shows a blank variable.

The object which i console.log shows this as its structure:

[image]

Its then sent to PHP with this :

```
    console.log(my_Obj);
    var as = JSON.stringify(my_Obj);        
    call_data('add.php?&as='+as, nxtFunc);
```

Now in the PHP file i have this which handles the situation:

```
    $path = json_decode($_GET['as']);
    echo $_GET['as'].'<br/>';
    print_r($path);
    die;
```

The result is:

```
[null,null,{\"8\":[null,null,null,null,null,null,[],[],[],[],[]],\"9\":
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]],\"10\":
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],[]],\"11\":
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]]}]   
<br/>
```

My XHR request url in Chrome shows:

```
add.php?as=[null,null,{%228%22:[null,null,null,null,null,null,[],[],[],[],[]],%229%22:[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]],%2210%22:[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[],[]],%2211%22:[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[]]}]
```

Notice the print_r shows nothing. Should i not be using stringify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `my_Obj` is an array and not an object.

Try this:

```
var as = JSON.stringify({data: my_Obj});
```

Note:

You will also need to clean up the array before stringifying - i.e. clear out all null/undefined indices. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/281335/921204

Comment: Why does Chrome say `[2: Object]` I thought it was an object which consisted of arrays inside of it ?

Comment: It says so because, it is an array with only one element whose index is 2 and value is a JS object.

Comment: Wait how come i have to remove the blank ones? For example why is this not allowed:

`[2: Object]
2: Object -> 8: Array[11] -> 6: Array[0] length: 0`

Comment: cleaning out the empty array elements would depend on structure expected. If specific indexes are expected  in php would cause problems

Comment: So PHP would not be happy with `6: Array[0] length: 0` ?

Comment: You can clear it out in such a way that the indices are not changed, only the empty ones removed. And in PHP check it like `isset(a[x])` and so on.