# js/jquery - how to get array values without index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array:

```
>>> var cars = new Array;
undefined

>>> cars[5] = 'Volvo';
"Volvo"

>>> cars[10] = 'Honda';
"Honda"

>>> cars
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "Volvo", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "Honda"]

>>> cars.length
11
```

Is there a way to get new array out of `cars` that is not sparse - like `['Volvo', 'Honda']`. Actually in my case even the order of the values would not matter.

Of course, I can do it with a loop but I'm looking for more elegant solution. `jQuery` is also an option!

Comment: Why do you need to specify keys explicitly if you don't care of them?

Comment: Already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Well, I index my array by the item ids, each id points to an object. I need to supply the objects as simple list to 3rd party library.

Comment: you can also use an object like a sparse array. use $.each() to iterate through the object.

Comment: Just as Levi I would suggest using an object. You do not even need a library to iterate the object, on modern browsers you can just use a for in loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) does array flattening automatically so:

```
var flattenedArr = $.map(cars, function(v) {
    return v;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9a8pB/1/)

Comment: Does it remove any falsy values or just undefined? Edit: nvm, I saw the fiddle now :)

Comment: And that's because jQuery [internally does loose comparison](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8-stable/src/core.js#L718) with `null` so `null == undefined //true`

Answer (score 2):

```
cars = $.grep(arr, function(n){
    return(n);
});
```

This just leaves the defined elements of your array and ignores the undefined ones.

[more info](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

Comment: This is a good solution, just one note: falsy values will be eliminated from the array this way. I guess `return typeof n !== 'undefined';` will do better in that aspect.