# How to remove a null element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application in which i am storing values in localstorage. By default my first value is null due to which i am getting error to run the code so i want to remove the first element and continue the processes. can anyone please help me how to remove first element from list?

Piece of my code is below:

```
var str = localStorage.getItem("appidlist");
var mySplitResult = str.split(",");
for(var i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++) {
   if (.....) {
      .
      .
   }    

}
```

where **str** returns null,1,2,3,.....
I hope my question is clear can anybody help me.

Comment: You can also check that you have something: `if (mySplitResult[i]) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

This should also work:

```
var str = localStorage.getItem("appidlist");
var mySplitResult = str.split(",");
mySplitResult.splice(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var str = localStorage.getItem("appidlist");
var mySplitResult = str.split(",").splice(1); // Remove the first item.
for(var i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++) {
    // Stuff
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for the response but it not solved the thing i am still getting this error                                          An error has occurred: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'str.split')

Comment: Whoops, `.shift()` should have been `.splice(1)`, try that. However, I think the problem might be that `str` is `null`. Are you certain that the `localStorage` contains a item with the name `appidlist` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.shift()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp).

```
mySplitResult.shift()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uing the `shift()` function, I would suggest you to create a function that return a new clean array. This will solve even the case where there are more than one (and in any postion) `null` value.

[You can use this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281335/1498857)