# Array of functions cleanup of empty slots

Tags: javascript, arrays

im having a problem, i have a array of functions which is frequently added to and removed from.

But when i do a foreach on the array it says that the index don't exist.

Input:
`arr[arr.length] = function () { Func() };`

Remove:
`delete arr[indexToRemove];`

for don't work now so i use a foreach
`for (key in arr)`

I'm getting a feeling that it is possible to overflow on the index so to prevent this i would like to find empty array positions and reposition the items in it.
This is what I'm thinking for cleanup atm.

```
    var temp = new Array();
    var count = 0;
    for (key in arr) {
        if (arr[key] != null) {
            temp[count] = arr[key];
            count++;
        }
    }
    arr = temp;
```

Is there a better solution and does a empty array of functions slot look like null?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/281264/1066234

Comment: late and its solved :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Don't use a `for...in` loop to iterate over an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description); use a standard counting `for` loop. Do use [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) instead of `arr[arr.length] = cont` to add new values. Also [don't use `delete` to remove an element from an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements); use [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

---

Input: `arr.push(cont)`;
Remove: `arr.splice(indexToRemove, 1);`

Comment: hmm that did not work though, when i used push instead of arr[arr.length] = cont; it broke. the splice worked though.

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail than that.

Comment: sorry i failed. wrote Push not push