# AngularJS: ng-repeat an array with keys

Tags: angularjs

I have an array with unordered keys, and I want to display them. The problem is that angular repeats it for all the keys, even when they are not set.

this is the code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{a[10]}}!

    <p ng-repeat="b in a">
        1. {{b}}
    </p>
</div>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.a = [];
    $scope.a[10] = "aaa";
}
</script>
```

and this is the output:

```
Hello, aaa!
1.
1.
1.
1.
1.
1.
1.
1.
1.
1.
1. aaa
```

i want only the array keys that are set to output. no empty b's please...
[here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HeVZJ/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In essence your problem is not AngularJS related but rather how JavaScript works.

If you have an empty array and you assign an element to position 10, then JavaScript will automatically resize the array to 11 elements (since an array index starts at zero) so the index is large enough to hold your element.

You could write extra code to filter the empty elements, but based on what you write, I think you would be better off with using an object to store your data.

I have created a plnkr for your convenience: http://plnkr.co/edit/apRLuJr4zqS2zbMz322Q?p=preview

```
// Array
$scope.sampleArray = [];
$scope.sampleArray[10] = 'test';

// Object
$scope.sampleObject = {};
$scope.sampleObject[10] = 'test';
```

As you can see the syntax is very similar, but the output is completely different.

By using an object, you will automatically eliminate the empty lines.

It will also keep your code simpler since you won't have to deal with the empty array elements.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of ways to do a cleanup on your array inside the controller (e.g. using `$watch`callback on `a` that would remove the empty elements from it whenever it changes).

Here's a solution that uses a simple custom filter, defined in a controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.namea = 'Superhero';
    $scope.a = [];
    $scope.a[10] = "aaa";

    $scope.myFilter = function(item){
        return item;
    }
}

<p ng-repeat="b in a | filter:myFilter">
  1. {{b}}
</p>
```

As stated in [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) docs, the 'filter' filter can take a function:

> function: A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters.
>   The function is called for each element of array. The final result is
>   an array of those elements that the predicate returned true for.

Comment: is there an option to do it without filters? what will happen to performance if the key is 1000?