# Split a string by integer in it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have long string like

```
"When I was 10 year old"
```

I have to get this string split to an array: `["When I was", "10" , "year old"]`.

The integer can be different in different cases and the sentence  may also change.

In short i want to split a string by integer in it
Is it possible?

How can i use regex in conjugation with split in Jquery/java-script

Comment: You don't use jquery for that.

Comment: What do you need this for? What's the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zQrfz/3)

```
var r = /\d+/;
var str = "When I was 10 year old";
var x = $.trim(str.match(r).toString());
var str_split = str.split(x);
var arr = [];
$.each(str_split, function (i, val) {
    arr.push($.trim(val));
    arr.push(x.toString());
});
arr.pop();
console.log(arr); // ["When I was", "10", "year old"]
```

Comment: You didn't test, I guess.

Comment: That simply finds the integer.  It doesn't split the string into an array, as he asking.

Comment: @dystroy done trim i know lot of code but i was just testing my skills without regex.

Comment: @dystroy can you please give some links from where i can learn regex.I know regex but only basics.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
var str = "When I was 10 year old";
var arr = str.match(/(\D*)\s(\d*)\s(\D*)/).slice(1);
```

Result :

```
["When I was", "10", "year old"]
```

Comment: var r = /\d+/;
var str="How are you 10 doing 12 today?";
var n=str.split(r); works

Comment: @xanatos I removed the need for filter with the last version

Comment: @Eez It wouldn't get the three parts required by OP

Comment: @dystroy it will do right? last remaining part after digits will be in 3rd one. But agree that makes it more specific.

Answer (score 4):

The regexp you're looking for is as simple as

```
/\D+|\d+/g
```

Example:

```
> str = "When I was 10 year old"
"When I was 10 year old"
> str.match(/\D+|\d+/g)
["When I was ", "10", " year old"]
```

To get rid of spaces:

```
> str.split(/(?:\s*(\d+)\s*)/g)
["When I was", "10", "year old"]
```

Comment: +1 You're right, even if it still needs trimming. Edit : just +1 now :)

Comment: [just saying] if the number is first then it is adding a empty element in the array which can be avoided using `filter` function as shown in this [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2843625/1577396).

Comment: How do I split a string with numeric and symbol like '30%'?

Comment: @georg no need, it surelly gonna get marked as duplicate, but I figured, it's num = str.split('%') but I am not sure if num[1] is gonna be the '%', bcz I also need that.