# How to fix this string into array using .split() method?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm having trouble with JS `.split()` method in a GAS script. I copy and paste the headers of other google sheet as variable `headers` (the usual way will be copy and paste). This pasted selection contains some empty and undefined elements. I need to turn this elements in an array. So I split it and use the `.filter`to clean empty elements. But, when I run the script, the var `arrayHeaders` remains equal to `headers`, as if the `.split(" ")` didn't make any change, this way:

[image]

This is my code:

```
var headers = "STUDENT  Parentage   GRADE   YEAR    DATE    GUIDE";
  var arrayHeaders = headers.split(" ");
//  arrayHeaders = arrayHeaders.filter(function(n){return n});
    Logger.log("headers = " + headers);
    Logger.log("arrayHeaders = " + arrayHeaders);
    Logger.log("arrayHeaders length " + arrayHeaders.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayHeaders.length; i++){      
      var NOME_Cell = sheet.getRange(1, i +1);
      Logger.log("NOME_Cell" + NOME_Cell);
      Logger.log("arrayHeaders[i]" + arrayHeaders[i]);     
      NOME_Cell.setValue(arrayHeaders[i]).setBackgroundRGB(34, 139, 34).setFontSize(font_size).setFontWeight("bold").setFontFamily("Arial");      
         }
```

If I delete all spaces after paste the string and press space again, then the `.split(" ")` works well.
Before asking this question, I read [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript), but I'm still stucked with what is going wrong here.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could your headers be tab separated instead of space separated?

Comment: yeah doesnt look like one " " would split them

Comment: You could just try `var arrayHeaders = headers.split(/[ \t]+/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your headers variable is not a String. Try this:

```
var arrayHeaders = headers.toString().split(/[\s\t]+/);
```

Comment: Hi, @Hallvar, I make a mistake about my comment that the `.split()` method couldn't be used in that object. I was using it twice! =)

Comment: I'll try your suggestion now!

Comment: Thanks, `headers.split(/[\s\t]+/)` was the solution. `typeof(headers)`show me that this was a string but the was tab and not spaces between the headers.

Answer (score 0):

When you are performing split(""), make sure the words in the string are seperated by samething which are passing to .split() method.
Your arrayHeaders is same as the headers.

```
var headers = "STUDENT Parentage GRADE YEAR DATE GUIDE";
  var arrayHeaders = headers.split(" ");
//  arrayHeaders = arrayHeaders.filter(function(n){return n});
    Logger.log("headers = " + headers);
    Logger.log("arrayHeaders = " + arrayHeaders);
    Logger.log("arrayHeaders length " + arrayHeaders.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayHeaders.length; i++){      
      var NOME_Cell = sheet.getRange(1, i +1);
      Logger.log("NOME_Cell" + NOME_Cell);
      Logger.log("arrayHeaders[i]" + arrayHeaders[i]);     
      NOME_Cell.setValue(arrayHeaders[i]).setBackgroundRGB(34, 139, 34).setFontSize(font_size).setFontWeight("bold").setFontFamily("Arial");      
    }
```

Here i think, the seperation of header is not same. make sure the seperation of headers are of one space or two spaces or three spaces..

Comment: Thanks, @shreedhar. There are 1 and 2 spaces. So I used the 1 space in `.split(" ");`.