# How to input text from user in HTML textarea and remove the HTML tags and also search through the textarea for a word?

Tags: javascript, html, search, find

I have the following code written,
it can get the text and remove the HTML tags but i cant or dont have the knowledge to write a code that search's the word which user types in a text input and shows the result.
How to do this by **HTML** and **JavaScript** ?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function stripHTML(){
        var re= /<\S[^><]*>/g
        for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
        arguments[i].value=arguments[i].value.replace(re, "")
        }
    </script>

<form>
    <textarea name="data1" style="width: 400px; height: 100px"></textarea><br />
    <input type="button" value="Remove HTML tags" onClick="stripHTML(this.form.data1)">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do, are you trying to find when/if the user types specified words?

Comment: I **think** he wants to take a value that is input into a textarea, strip out any HTML, and then update the texatarea with the new value (but I'm also not 100% of that) . . .

Comment: Im trying to get HTML code from user, strip out HTML tags. then user can request or look for a word that wishes to search/find from the new text. did i make it better or worse?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a totally rewritten answer which contains some significant changes.

First off, I added a bit to your Html so there would be a place for the text to go once the tags were stripped, as well as a textarea and buttons for searching the cleaned-up text:

```
<form>
    <textarea name="data1" style="width: 400px; height: 100px"></textarea><br />
    <input type="button" value="Remove HTML tags" onclick="stripHTML(this.form.data1)">
</form>
<hr>
<h3><b>Output (no HTML tags):</b></h3>
<p id="output"></p>
<hr>
<form>
    <textarea name="data2" id="search"></textarea></br>
    <input type="button" value="Search Output for Word" onclick="searchMe(this.form.data2)">
</form>
<hr>
```

Next, I added the following javascript:

```
// used to remove empty strings from array:
Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
            this.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return this;
};

// Gets rid of the html tags in the first `textarea`.
stripHTML = function(text) {
    var re = /<\S[^><]*>/g;
    var newText = text.value.replace(re, "");
    showText(newText);
}

// Puts stripped text into "output" `p` tag.
showText = function(text) {
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
    outputDiv.innerHTML = text;
}

// Searches output text for word in `search` textarea.
searchMe = function(searchWord) {
    var text = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
    if(text) {
        // assuming your words will be split by spaces.
        var wordList = text.split(' ');
        wordList.clean('');
        if (wordList.length === 1) {
            alert('only one word!');
        } else {
            var message = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
                if (wordList[i].toLowerCase() === searchWord.value.toLowerCase()) {
                    if (i === 0) {
                        message += [wordList[i],wordList[i+1]].join('-');
                    } else if (i === wordList.length-1) {
                        message += [wordList[i-1],wordList[i]].join('-');
                    } else {
                        message += [wordList[i-1],wordList[i],wordList[i+1]].join('-');
                    }
                    message += "---Word#:"+(i+1)+"\n";
                }
            }
            if (message) alert("Prev-This-Next:\n\n"+message);
            else alert ('No matches!');
        }
    } else {
        alert('press "Remove HTML tags" first!');
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is close to what you were looking for!

References:

1. [Array.prototype.clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript) function.

Comment: Im trying to get HTML code from user, strip out HTML tags. then user can request or look for a word that wishes to search/find from the new text.
did i make it better or worse?

Comment: Do you want the stripped text to display in its own `div`? How do you want the user to be able to search? Normally it's possible to use a browser's built-in search function to find text on a page.

Comment: yes it would be better to be shown in its own div. and i want to include the search box in the page to request a word search, and what could be better is that when the result is shown, not only it shows the word searched for also shows the previous and next word.

Comment: Check out [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/EcLDq/6/). I'll post it as an answer & answer questions if you think it's good

Comment: It's great. I had one issue with it, Is when tags are removed, search output only displays "only one word" alert.
I have to work on the search part which can also display the previous and next word.

Comment: It should only display "only one word" when the text only has one word - so there shouldn't be a previous or next word. But that can be taken out pretty easily