# Nodejs/Javascript Getting Process Memory of any process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a way of getting the process memory of any process running.

I am doing a web application. I have a server (through Nodejs), my file app.js, and an agent sending information to app.js through the server.

I would like to find a way to get the process memory of any process (in order to then sending this information to the agent)  ?
Do you have any idea how I can do this ? I have searched on google but I haven't found my answer :/

Thank you

PS : I need a windows compatible solution :)

Comment: Do you want the memory usage of any process, or any *node* process?

Comment: I want the memory usage of any process

Comment: You want the process memory *size* or the actual data?

Comment: hmmm (I think) I would like the actual data.

Trying to be clear, I want to display on a graph the evolution of the % of the memory used by the process (each second, I want the % of memory). Do you see what I mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Windows**
>
> For windows, use `tasklist` instead of `ps`

In the example below, i use the `ps` unix program, so it's not windows compatible.

Here, the %MEM is the 4st element of each `finalProcess` iterations.

*On `Windows` the %MEM is the 5th element.*

```
var myFunction = function(processList) {
  // here, your code
};

var parseProcess = function(err, process, stderr) {
    var process = (process.split("\n")),
        finalProcess = [];

    // 1st line is a tab descriptor
    // if Windows, i should start to 2
    for (var i = 1; i < process.length; i++) {
        finalProcess.push(cleanArray(process[i].split(" ")));
    }

    console.log(finalProcess);
    // callback to another function
    myFunction(finalProcess);
};

var getProcessList = function() {

    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('ps aux', parseProcess.bind(this));
}

// thx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript
function cleanArray(actual){
  var newArray = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i<actual.length; i++){
      if (actual[i]){
        newArray.push(actual[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}


getProcessList();
```

Comment: arf, I should have specified I am working with windows

But thank you for your answer, I hope it would help other people :)

Comment: Updated answer, it should work on Windows with this little fix (use `tasklist` instead of `ps`).

Comment: and may I bother you one last time ? :) How can I put the array in a variable, to use it after ? Because I have tried to put some " return" in parseProcess and getprocessList, but it is not working and I always retrieve an object with stdout etc. Thank you

Comment: You need to set a callback in `parseProcess` (view edit)

Comment: Vote up for this answer please

Comment: Sorry but I can't, I don't have enough reputation :/. I will do this as soon as I can.