# javascript .filter() true booleans

Tags: javascript, filter, boolean

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  // Don't show a false ID to this bouncer.
    function a(b) {
      if(b !== false) {
        return b;
      }
    }

    arr = arr.filter(a);
    return arr;
}

bouncer([7, 'ate', '', false, 9]);
```

I have to return true boolean statements only, and when I run this code, it works. However, I am quite confused because my "if statement" will work whether it's b !== true or b !== false. Could someone please explain the reason why this works both ways?

Comment: Related - [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2843625/104380)

Comment: It's amazing how many people in here didn't even answer the actual question you were asking.

Answer (score 85):

Apparently [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) was introduced in ES5.

This definitely helped me wrap my mind around what's going on here. Hope it helps!

Essentially, writing:

```
arr.filter(Boolean)
```

is the same as writing:

```
arr.filter( function(x) { return Boolean(x); });
```

since [`Boolean()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) is also a function that returns truthy when `true` and falsy when `false`!

Example:

```js
var a = [1, 2, "b", 0, {}, "", NaN, 3, undefined, null, 5];

var b = a.filter(Boolean);  // [1, 2, "b", {}, 3, 5];
```

Source: [here](http://www.devign.me/javascript-tip-remove-falsy-items-out-of-an-array).

Answer (score 61):

I was solving a similar problem and came up with this:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
console.log(bouncer([7, 'ate', '', false, 9]));
```

Answer (score 15):

simplest way to do it :

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    return arr.filter(x => !!x);
}
```

Comment: Using `arr.filter(Boolean)` is simpler

Comment: @NickA Why does filter(Boolean) determine false as falsy, whereas Boolean(false) is truthy?

Comment: @user25976 a `Boolean` is an *object*, and all objects are truthy, however the *primitive* `false` is just `false`

Comment: You don't need `!!x`. Just `arr.filter(x => x);` is enough.

Comment: @user25976 `Boolean(false)` returns `false`. `new Boolean(false)` returns an object. The keyword `new` makes the difference.

Answer (score 6):

It's because you return the value. The filter function should return true or false like this:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    arr = arr.filter(function(x) { console.log(x === true)
       if(x !== false) {
           return true;
       }
    });
    return arr;
}
```

or shorter:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(x) { console.log(x === true)
       return x !== false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function acts is it does because JavaScript values in boolean comparisons are "truthy" or "falsey". Non-booleans are coerced to a boolean value when used in a boolean context (comparisons, if statements, etc.)

If I understand your intent, you can modify your function to get your expected output like this:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  // Don't show a false ID to this bouncer.
    function a(b) {
      if(typeof(b) === 'boolean' && !b) {
        return new Boolean(b);
      }
    }

    arr = arr.filter(a);
    return arr;
}

bouncer([7, 'ate', '', false, 9, true]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this exercise and was playing about with it somewhat. It ended up helping me understand it a bit better, so if you may I will add a bit of clarity to this bouncer function.

```
function bouncerOne(array){

let truthy = array.filter(x => x);
// This takes the .filter() and applies the anon function where it takes 
// the value and returns the positive value. All values that are not Falsy including 
// objects and functions would return True. 
console.log("The Truth is:", truthy);//this Outputs the result to the console.
let falsy = array.filter(x => !x); 
//This takes the .filer() and applies the 
//annon function where it takes the value and only returns items that ARE NOT True. 
//So Falsy Values are taken. 
console.log("The Falsy Values are",falsy);

//The annon function of (x => x) & (x => !x)
// really makes use of the strict equality power of JavaScript. 
// Where simple conditional test can be carried out.
};
console.log(bouncerOne([7, "ate", "", false, 9,null,42,"Bingo",undefined,NaN]));
//Returns: The Truth is: [ 7, 'ate', 9, 42, 'Bingo' ]
//The Falsy Values are [ '', false, null, undefined, NaN ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Double Not operator ( !! ) convert value into Boolean form.
eg : !!true // true;

```js
let a = [1, 2, "b", 0, {}, "", NaN, 3, undefined, null, 5];

// writing in ES6 syntax
a.filter(v=>!!v); // [1, 2, 'b', {…}, 3, 5]

// writing with function keyword
a.filter( function(v) { return (!!v); }); // [1, 2, 'b', {…}, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically, your if statement is not doing anything in this code because it is not changing arr which you are returning as output. If you set b!== true or false it has no effect. Even if you remove the "if statement", you will get same answer.