# Conditionally applying class attributes in React

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs, class-attributes

I want to conditionally show and hide this button group depending on what is passed in from the parent component which looks like this:

```
    <TopicNav showBulkActions={this.__hasMultipleSelected} />
```

```
    __hasMultipleSelected: function() {
      return false; //return true or false depending on data
    }
```

```
    var TopicNav = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-6">
                <div className="btn-group pull-right {this.props.showBulkActions ? 'show' : 'hidden'}">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Bulk Actions <span className="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul className="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Merge into New Session</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Add to Existing Session</a></li>
                      <li className="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
      }
    });
```

Nothing is happening however, with the `{this.props.showBulkActions ? 'show' : 'hidden'}`. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: You may also wish to consider [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/), since this abstracts some of the class stuff into component properties, making what you're trying to do a little easier.

Answer (score 841, accepted):

The curly braces are inside the string, so it is being evaluated as string. They need to be outside, so this should work:

```
<div className={"btn-group pull-right " + (this.props.showBulkActions ? 'show' : 'hidden')}>
```

Note the space after "pull-right". You don't want to accidentally provide the class "pull-rightshow" instead of "pull-right show". Also the parentheses needs to be there.

Comment: Thanks! I had to modify it slightly because for some reason it wasn't outputting btn-group pull-right at all. Just show or hidden.

Comment: This is particularly helpful in certain cases where `classnames` might not be appropriate. If you are in your `render` function and you have a `map`, you might only know whether you want to add a class at the time you are rendering it, so this answer is quite useful for that.

Comment: great alternative instead of having a bunch of conditional templates in your render or return

Comment: @apexdodge what modification you had to do. I have the same issue.

Comment: @RamY One way is to put all the classes inside the conditional 
`this.props.showBulkActions ? 'btn-group pull-right show' : 'btn-group pull-right hidden')`.
Not elegant but it works.

Comment: the way react handle this is so out of convention.

Answer (score 132):

As others have commented, [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) utility is the currently recommended approach to handle conditional CSS class names in ReactJs.

In your case, the solution will look like:

```
var btnGroupClasses = classNames(
  'btn-group',
  'pull-right',
  {
    'show': this.props.showBulkActions,
    'hidden': !this.props.showBulkActions
  }
);
```

...

```
<div className={btnGroupClasses}>...</div>
```

As a side note, I would suggest you to try to avoid using both `show` and `hidden` classes, so the code could be simpler. Most likely, you don't need to set a class for something to be shown by default.

**2021 addendum:** for performance improvement, you can look into [clsx](https://github.com/lukeed/clsx) as an alternative.

Comment: Could you elaborate on classNames utility being the "currently recommended approach"?  Is that captured in some well-regarded best practices document somewhere?  Or just sort of the word of mouth around React and `classNames` at the moment?

Comment: @anied At the time of writing it was recommended in official React documentation: http://web.archive.org/web/20160602124910/http://facebook.github.io:80/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html

Comment: It is still mentioned in [latest documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20180829094008/https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#how-do-i-add-css-classes-to-components): "*If you often find yourself writing code like this, classnames package can simplify it.*"

Comment: As of 2021, instead of `classnames` you might want to try [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx)

Comment: _classnames_ is still mentioned [here](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#how-to-apply-multiple-css-classes-conditionally) - "_To make this more readable, you can use a tiny helper library like classnames_"

Answer (score 113):

If you are using a transpiler (such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or Traceur) you can use the new ES6 "[template strings](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings)".

Here is the answer of @spitfire109, modified accordingly:

```
<div className={`btn-group pull-right ${this.props.showBulkActions ? 'shown' : 'hidden'}`}>
```

This approach allows you to do neat things like that, rendering either `s-is-shown` or `s-is-hidden`:

```
<div className={`s-${this.props.showBulkActions ? 'is-shown' : 'is-hidden'}`}>
```

Comment: Be careful with the second approach, especially in large codebases, as it makes the class strings less greppable. For example, if someone searches for `s-is-shown` or `s-is-hidden` in the codebase, they won't find this code.

Answer (score 27):

you can simply do the following for example.

```
let classNameDependsOnCondtion = i18n.language == 'en' ? "classname" : "";

className={`flex flex-col lg:flex-row list-none ${classNameDependsOnCondtion }`}
```

OR

```
className={`flex flex-col lg:flex-row list-none ${i18n.language == 'en' ? "classname" : ""}`}
```

Comment: If you are conditionally rendering a single className inline and don't want a class to appear for one of the conditions, you can return `null` or `undefined` instead of an empty string.  Example: `className={condition ? 'red' : null}` or `className={condition ? 'red' : undefined}`

It's better to keep your markup clean rather than having elements appear like `<div class>` or `<div class="null">

Comment: @AnthonyAvila true, also its better to use classnames https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames to avoid printing extra empty spaces.

Answer (score 21):

You can use here String literals

```
const Angle = ({show}) => {

   const angle = `fa ${show ? 'fa-angle-down' : 'fa-angle-right'}`;

   return <i className={angle} />
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Replace:

```
<div className="btn-group pull-right {this.props.showBulkActions ? 'show' : 'hidden'}">`
```

with:

```
<div className={`btn-group pull-right ${this.props.showBulkActions ? 'show' : 'hidden'}`}
```

Answer (score 15):

In case you will need only one optional class name:

```
<div className={"btn-group pull-right " + (this.props.showBulkActions ? "show" : "")}>
```

Comment: This will append `false` class when condition fails.

Comment: instead of "" in the ternary use null, if not, the class property is set in the element, with null not, it's better

Answer (score 14):

Or use npm [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames). It is very easy and useful especially for constructing  the list of classes

Answer (score 13):

Expending on @spitfire109's fine answer, one could do something like this:

```
rootClassNames() {
  let names = ['my-default-class'];
  if (this.props.disabled) names.push('text-muted', 'other-class');

  return names.join(' ');
}
```

and then within the render function:

```
<div className={this.rootClassNames()}></div>
```

keeps the jsx short

Answer (score 12):

You can use ES6 arrays instead of classnames.
The answer is based on Dr. Axel Rauschmayer article: [Conditionally adding entries inside Array and object literals](http://2ality.com/2017/04/conditional-literal-entries.html).

```
<div className={[
                 "classAlwaysPresent", 
                 ...Array.from(condition && ["classIfTrue"])
                ].join(" ")} />
```

Comment: please expand upon this, what is condition?

Comment: const condition = (1 === 1);

Answer (score 12):

2019:

React is lake a lot of utilities. But you don't need any `npm` package for that. just create somewhere the function `classnames` and call it when you need it;

```
function classnames(obj){
  return Object.entries(obj).filter( e => e[1] ).map( e=>e[0] ).join(' ');
}
```

or

```
function classnames(obj){
 return Object.entries(obj).map( ([cls,enb]) => enb? cls: '' ).join(' ');
}
```

example

```
  stateClass= {
    foo:true,
    bar:false,
    pony:2
  }
  classnames(stateClass) // return 'foo pony'
```

```
 <div className="foo bar {classnames(stateClass)}"> some content </div>
```

#### Just For Inspiration

declaring helper DOM element and using it native `toggle` method:

`(DOMToken​List)classList.toggle(class,condition)`

example:

```
const classes = document.createElement('span').classList; 

function classstate(obj){
  for( let n in obj) classes.toggle(n,obj[n]);
 return classes; 
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
<div className={['foo', condition && 'bar'].filter(Boolean).join(' ')} />
```

[`.filter(Boolean)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31523737/104380) removes "falsey" values from the array. Since class names must be *strings*, anything other than that would not be included in the *new* filtered array.

```js
console.log(  ['foo', true  && 'bar'].filter(Boolean).join(' ')  )
console.log(  ['foo', false && 'bar'].filter(Boolean).join(' ')  )
```

### [Above written as a function](https://gist.github.com/yairEO/105b10b0f13b8f33268ed5feb55108f1):

```
const cx = (...list) => list.filter(Boolean).join(' ')

// usage:
<div className={cx('foo', condition && 'bar')} />
```

```js
var cx = (...list) => list.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
console.log(  cx('foo', 1 && 'bar', 1 && 'baz')  )
console.log(  cx('foo', 0 && 'bar', 1 && 'baz')  )
console.log(  cx('foo', 0 && 'bar', 0 && 'baz')  )
```

Answer (score 9):

simply use this approach--

```
<div className={`${this.props.showActions ? 'shown' : 'hidden'}`}>
```

this is much more neat and clean.

Answer (score 8):

More elegant solution, which is better for maintenance and readability:

```
const classNames = ['js-btn-connect'];

if (isSelected) { classNames.push('is-selected'); }

<Element className={classNames.join(' ')}/>
```

Comment: Cleanest approach imo. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can use this:

```
<div className={"btn-group pull-right" + (this.props.showBulkActions ? ' show' : ' hidden')}>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to tailored my answer to include all the best possible solution in the post

There are many different ways of getting this done.

#### 1. Inline inside the class

```
<div className={`... ${this.props.showBulkActions ? 'show' : 'hidden'}`}>
  ...
</div>
```

#### 2. Using the values

```
var btnClass = classNames(
  ...
  {
    'show': this.props.showBulkActions,
    'hidden': !this.props.showBulkActions
  }
);
```

#### 3. Using a variable

```
let dependentClass = this.props.showBulkActions ? 'show' : 'hidden';

className={`... ${dependentClass }`}
```

#### 4. Using [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx)

```
<div className={clsx('...',`${this.props.showBulkActions ? 'show' : 'hidden'}`)}>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is useful when you have more than one class to append. You can join all classes in array with a space.

```
const visibility = this.props.showBulkActions ? "show" : ""
<div className={["btn-group pull-right", visibility].join(' ')}>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work for you

```
var TopicNav = React.createClass({
render: function() {

let _myClasses = `btn-group pull-right {this.props.showBulkActions?'show':'hidden'}`;

return (
            ...
            <div className={_myClasses}>
               ...
            </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference to @split fire answer, we can update it with template literals, which is more readable,For reference [Checkout javascript template literal](https://blog.tildeloop.com/posts/javascript-template-literals)

```
<div className={`btn-group pull-right ${this.props.showBulkActions ? 'show' : 'hidden'}`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-class-list) npm package. It handles everything and has options for static and dynamic classes based on a variable or a function.

```
// Support for string arguments
getClassNames('class1', 'class2');

// support for Object
getClassNames({class1: true, class2 : false});

// support for all type of data
getClassNames('class1', 'class2', null, undefined, 3, ['class3', 'class4'], { 
    class5 : function() { return false; },
    class6 : function() { return true; }
});

<div className={getClassNames('show', {class1: true, class2 : false})} /> // "show class1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the value of `this.props.showBulkActions` you can switch classes dynamically as follows.

```
<div ...{...this.props.showBulkActions 
? { className: 'btn-group pull-right show' } 
: { className: 'btn-group pull-right hidden' }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that you can also use a **variable content** as a part of the class

```
<img src={src} alt="Avatar" className={"img-" + messages[key].sender} />
```

The context is a chat between a bot and a user, and the styles change depending of the sender, this is the browser result:

```
<img src="http://imageurl" alt="Avatar" class="img-bot">
```

Answer (score 0):

A function to return the correct class based on a param (if present)

```
  getClass(param){
    let podClass = 'classA'
    switch(param.toLowerCase()){
        case 'B':
            podClass  = 'classB'
            break;
        case 'C':
            podClass  = 'classC'
            break;
    }
    return podClass
}
```

Now just invoke this function from the div where the corresponding class is to be applied.

```
 <div className={anyOtherClass + this.getClass(param)}
```

I successfully used this logic to apply the correct color to my bootstrap table rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className={"h-3 w-3 rounded-full my-auto " + (index.endDate ==="present"? "bg-green-500":"bg-red-500")}></div>
```

> Don't Forget to add an extra space after the static class names.