# How to conditionally apply CSS classes in React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've been musing on how best to conditionally apply a CSS class in React JS. I've seen some answers banding around but there aren't many out there or they're just not as elaborative as I'd like.

Comment: What have you already tried?  Conditional on what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)

Comment: Hi Makyen, thanks for responding. Ive been using Angular 1.x heavily previously and since jumping on React, I wanted to achieve the same method as with ng-class and applying classes conditionally.

I played around with it some more and shared what I found.

Answer (score 41):

You can simply condition class to state, like this:

```
<div className={ this.state.exampleIsTruthy ? 'yourClass' : '' }>
  text
</div>
```

or if you want to switch classes based on a state like this:

```
<div className={ this.state.exampleTrueOrFalse ? 'shown' : 'hidden' }>
  text
</div>
```

Comment: Your first example throws a console error: 

`Warning: Received false for a non-boolean attribute className.`

You need to use a ternary regardless unfortunately, even if the second value is empty:

`this.state.exampleTrueOrFalse ? 'yourClass' : '' `

Comment: @Peadar I have updated my answer. Got that myself sometime ago but didn't think to update the answer. Thank you ✌

Comment: If the condition is false, then a class name of empty string will be added, and the class list will contain a double space, right?

Comment: @bytrangle probably yes. If that's a problem, maybe returning `null` instead of `''`will work better 

Comment: Is there a shorter way instead of `true ? "x" : ""`? Like `true && "x"` for classNames?

Answer (score 23):

The React documentation on [manipulating class names](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html) suggests the [`classnames`](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) NPM package.

The docs for the package are great.

The following snippet is straight from the package `README`: [**Usage** section](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#usage)

```
classNames('foo', 'bar');                 // => 'foo bar'
classNames('foo', { bar: true });         // => 'foo bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': true });          // => 'foo-bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': false });         // => ''
classNames({ foo: true }, { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
classNames({ foo: false, bar: true });    // => 'bar'

// lots of arguments of various types
classNames('foo', { bar: true, duck: false }, 'baz', { quux: true }); 
// => 'foo bar baz quux'

// other falsy values are just ignored
classNames(null, false, 'bar', undefined, 0, 1, { baz: null }, ''); 
// => 'bar 1'
```

Answer (score 13):

Many answers assume this is about conditionally toggling CSS classes (*ternary if* is adequate), but this become far more obtuse when you need to optionally include classnames. Multiple ternary ifs with empty false expressions is verbose. An NPM package may be a tad much. A function too may be overkill for some.

Here's what I do.

```
const classNames = [
  "className1",
  condition1 && "className2",
  condition2 && "className3",
  condition3 && "className4",
].filter(e => e).join(" ");
```

**Edit as of June 2021**

I'm noticing this answer still sees the occasional upvote. Thought
I'd provide a slightly updated example using a small and succinct arrow function:

```
const cls = (...classes) => classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ');

<div className={cls('mandatoryClass', condition && 'optionalClass')} />
```

Comment: Hi. I think you are a genius. Maybe you need to develop your example a little more, but it is perfect

Answer (score 6):

If you need to add a conditional class to an existing class, this one may give you an idea

```
<span className={'fa ' + (this.state.dropdownActive ? 'fa-angle-up' : 'fa-angle-down')}></span>
```

in this example, I am showing an arrow icon for a dropdown depending on the state of the dropdown. I need to keep the class `fa` for any case to set the font-family of the span, and I only need to switch between `fa-angle-up` and `fa-angle-down`.

Same example with template literals

```
<span className={`fa ${this.state.dropdownActive ? 'fa-angle-up' : 'fa-angle-down'}`}></span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Classnames library https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

> The classNames function takes any number of arguments which can be a
>   string or object. If
>   the value of the key is falsy, it won't be included in the output.

```
var classNames = require('classnames');

var Button = React.createClass({
  // ...
  render () {
    var btnClass = classNames({
      'btn': true,
      'btn-pressed': false,
      'btn-over': true
    });
    // output: btnClass = "btn btn-over"
    return <button className={btnClass}>{this.props.label}</button>;
  }
});
```

Take a look at the doc and let me know if you have any questions!

Cheers

Comment: could you expand on this to make this usable

Answer (score 4):

The solution which is stated below by other author in above comment works for me

```
<div className={ this.state.end ? 'hidden' : 'shown' }>text</div>
```

Just a add on if you want to add more classes then add class separated by space.

Answer (score 3):

For the record I think the `classnames` library answers are the most correct, but if you didn't want to pull in another dependency, you could roll your own simple implementation that works kind of like jQuery:

```
function getClassBuilder () {
    return {
        array: [],
        add: function (className) {
            if (this.array.indexOf(className) < 0) {
                this.array.push(className);
            }
        },
        remove: function (className) {
            var index = this.array.indexOf(className);
            if (index > -1) {
                this.array.splice(index, 1);
            }
        },
        toString: function () {
            return this.array.join(' ');
        }
    }
}
```

then, when you need to use it:

```
var builder = getClassBuilder();
builder.add('class1');
builder.add('class2');
if (condition) { builder.remove('class1') };

<a href="#" className={builder.toString()}>Button</a>
```

Comment: The classnames library itself is tiny, you sort of rewrote it here. I'd suggest sticking to classnames: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames/blob/master/index.js

Comment: For the record, I agree. My post was aimed at the ["not invented here"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) crowd.

Answer (score 0):

**Single Condition with Static ClassName**

```
<div className={"container " + (this.props.condition === true ? 'show' : 'hidden')}>
```

**Double Condition with Static ClassName**

```
<div className={"container " + (this.props.condition === true ? 'show ' : 'hidden ') + (this.props.secondCondition === true ? 'visible' : 'invisible')}>
```

need to give space between conditional class or static class by the end

Answer (score 0):

I find this tiny (~220 Bytes) package extremely helpful to avoid writing a lot of boilerplate code:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

You could simply write:

```
import clsx from 'clsx';

<section className={clsx('zb-card', <some dynamic optional classNames>)}>
or
<section className={clsx('foo', true && 'bar', 'baz')}>
//=> 'foo bar baz'
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so I've been experimenting and it turns out there are ways and it's not as hard as I thought. 
This might help those just starting out in React JS.

So there are two ways of doing so and two reasons for adding in-line styles:

(1) Add class name inside a style attribute as an object so it can be styled inside a regular CSS stylesheet, directly inside a JSX file or used for conditional CSS

EXAMPLE 1

```
const classNameAsAPlainObject = {
        color: '#333333',
        backgroundColor: '#999999'
}

<a href="#" className="an-existing-class" style={classNameAsAPlainObject} >
Button
</a>
```

EXAMPLE 2

```
const conditionIsSomething = {
    color: 'red'
}
<a href="#" className="an-existing-class" style={conditionIsSomething ? 'classNameBasedOnCondition' : ' ' }>
Button
</a>
```

> In the second example, two different classes can be declared depending
>   on desired result or one class can be declared if condition is true or
>   none if condition is false.

(2) Add it to the regular className attribute where a condition is required but be sure to accommodate for existing class names and be aware that this method requires styling in a regular CSS file. If no condition is required, then add the class as per normal to a className attribute.

EXAMPLE 3

```
<a href="#" className={"an-existing-class " + (conditionIsSomething ? 'thisClass' : 'thatClass')}>
Button
</a>
```

EXAMPLE 4

```
<a href="#" className={"an-existing-class " + (conditionIsSomething ? 'aClassIsAdded' : ' ')}>
Button
</a>
```

> Again, if the condition requires it, one class can be declared or none
>   as seen in example 4. Be sure to leave a space in either case after
>   the "an-existing-class" and before the closing quote so there’s a space
>   for the conditional class.

So I guess as a general rule of thumb, you're adding a class and styling as an object (as with Example 1 and 2), you can style it within the JSX file, but if adding a class name to the "className" attribute, you will be styling it inside a regular CSS file. I haven't experimented with this actually so I will give that a try. If anyone finds otherwise, please enlighten me.

Comment: This is not a good practice. The classnames library is designed for this, small, and makes the JSX highly readable.

Comment: Noted! Thanks for the heads up