# Adding a specific styling to a specific item of a mapped array in React

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

```
const allTodos = [{id: 1, name: 'whatever user type'}, { }, { }, .... { }] // Defined as an array using setState in other file. Imported in this file as allTodos using props.

export const Todos = (props) => {

props.allTodos.map((prev) => {
return (

<div id="item_container">

<button type='button' className = 'check_button'
onClick = {() => setActiveTodos(prev.id)}>

<img src = {check} alt="" id = "check_img"></img>

</button>

<li id="li_item">{prev.name}</li>
</div>

)}
}
```

Now, the question is I want to add some specific style to the element(Button) clicked upon on. The styling I want to add is just change the background of the Button clicked upon.
I tried using conditional to set className but the styling was added to every item. So, it didn't work out.

Comment: Could you provide a codesanbox for this?

Comment: So you want to change the button's background when you click on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[conditional class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281032/how-to-conditionally-apply-css-classes-in-react-js/51264578) - selecting particular class based on condition (in this case - if the activeTodos state == current index)

```
props.allTodos.map((prev, i) => {
            <button type = 'button' key ={i}
            className= {`${prev.id == activeTodos ? "active" : "inactive"}
            onClick={e => setActiveTodos(prev.id)}} 
            </button>
        }
```

---

There is some combinations (eg. There can be selected only 1 item per time or 4)

If You wan't 4 items selected (eg from 6) - then there is possiblity to hold active ids in array.

Comment: What is i here?

Comment: Ya, it worked. I was doing the same like you did but I was writing the conditional in a function defined outside of the map method and referencing the function name in the className. But, that was adding the className to all items. But, it worked after I wrote the conditional in ClassName like you did and it worked. Thanks for the help. I was stuck at this for the past 10 hours.

Comment: Where do you close the ``?

Comment: There's only 1 ` backtick here

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution to this is using "Code Splitting".
Just create a Button as a separate component and place the state inside the Button component.

```
const Button = ()=>{
const [ActiveTodos,  setActiveTodos]=useState();
return (   
<button type='button' className = 'check_button'
    onClick = {() => setActiveTodos(prev.id)}>
    <img src = {check} alt="" id = "check_img"></img>
    </button> 
);
}

export const Todos = (props) => {

props.allTodos.map((prev) => {
return (

<div id="item_container">

<Button />

<li id="li_item">{prev.name}</li>
</div>

)}
}
```

This will create seperate state for each item in the map so tha the styling can be applied only to a particular item.