# Writing conditional statement inside render function in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

My state is `{visibilityFilter: "completed"}` or `{visibilityFilter: "todo"}`. Based on this I want to assign classnames to an element. Something like this,

```
<span {this.state.visibilityFilter=="completed"?className="active":className:""}>Completed</span>
```

But it's not working. I tried different variations of it,

```
{<span this.state.visibilityFilter=="completed"?className="active":className:"">Completed</span>}
```

But none of them are working. I know that it can work if I create a variable outside return statement and assign it in HTML. Like this,

```
let classCompleted = this.state.visibilityFilter == "completed"? "active":"";
```

and then,

```
<span className={`$(classCompleted)`}></span>
```

But I want to know how to do evaluate class in return statement.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35718621/3231537) seems a perfect match for your question

Comment: @Icepickle: I should have realized it would be a duplicate, good find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close, you just put the `className` part outside:

```
<span className={this.state.visibilityFilter=="completed" ? "active" : ""} onClick={this.handleFilter.bind(this,'completed')}>Completed</span>
```

---

Off-topic side note:

Using `bind` in the `onClick` every time means you'll re-bind every time that element is *rendered*. You might consider doing it once, in the component's constructor:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.handleFilter = this.handleFilter.bind(this);
        // ...
    }
    handleFilter() {
        // ...
    }
    render() {
        return <span className={this.state.visibilityFilter=="completed" ? "active" : ""} onClick={this.handleFilter}>Completed</span>;
    }
}
```

Another option is to make it an arrow function, if you've enabled class properties in your transpiler (they're in the `stage-2` preset in Babel as of this writing, January 2017):

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    // ...
    handleFilter = event => {
        // ...
    };
    render() {
        return <span className={this.state.visibilityFilter=="completed" ? "active" : ""} onClick={this.handleFilter}>Completed</span>;
    }
}
```

Live example of that one:

```js
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        visibilityFilter: ""
      };
    }
    handleFilter = event => {
      this.setState({
        visibilityFilter: "completed"
      });
    };
    render() {
        return <span className={this.state.visibilityFilter == "completed" ? "active" : ""} onClick={this.handleFilter}>Completed</span>;
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <YourComponent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Although that's perfectly correct, isn't classNames the better way to go, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35718621/3231537)?

Comment: @Icepickle: Obviously one is free to use an extra library if one wants.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the answer and advice.

Comment: @AnuragAwasthi Please just use `classNames` library. I tried it with and without and it's so amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Use [classNames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames), A simple javascript utility for conditionally joining classNames together.

Note: I've added the `state` and `todo` classes to demonstrate working with multiple classes. btw - the comments are not valid JSX, so don't use the code as is.

```
<span className={
    state: true, // always 
    active: this.state.visibilityFilter === "completed", // conditional
    todo: this.state.visibilityFilter !== "todo" // conditional
}>
Completed
</span>}
```

Example (based on [T.J. Crowder`s code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41531966/5157454)):

```js
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        visibilityFilter: ""
      };
    }
    handleFilter = event => {
      this.setState({
        visibilityFilter: "completed"
      });
    };
    render() {
        return (
          <span className={classNames({
          state: true,
          active: this.state.visibilityFilter === "completed"
        })} onClick={this.handleFilter}>Completed
        </span>
       );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <YourComponent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.state {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.2.5/index.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I wanted to know what was problem with my jsx.

Comment: For that you've got @T.J.Crowder answer :) I thought you might like to know that the **classNames** option exists.