# How to apply a CSS style in React based on condition and incorporate it with another class?

Tags: reactjs

I am modifying the value of a property for certain list items in an array, depending on whether or not a checkbox is checked/unchecked. The list items are named `todo` and the property where I am storing whether or not the checkbox is checked/unchecked (T/F) on a given todo, is called `completed`

Given this handler, where I am adjusting the value of an individual todo's completed property when a check box is checked/unchecked:

```
handleCompletedTodo(todo) {
    var completedTodoId = todo.id;
    var found = this.state.todos.find(todosArray=>todosArray.id === completedTodoId);
      if(found) found.completed = !found.completed;
  }
```

How can I now set a CSS conditional style to it's text (named: "strike-through") in this stateless component, to indicate that a todo's item's completed value is T/F? Please note there is already a class that is present called "list-group-item", which will have to be incorporated with the conditional style:

```
<ul className = "list-group">
      {props.todosArray.map(todo => {
          return <li className='list-group-item' key ={todo.id}><input type="checkbox" onChange= {() => props.onDone(todo)}/>{todo.text}<a onClick={() => props.onEdit(todo)}
          className="edit-todo glyphicon glyphicon-edit d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" href="#"></a><a onClick={() => props.onDelete(todo)}
          className="delete-todo glyphicon glyphicon-trash" href="#"></a></li>
        })
      }
    </ul>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator to and ES6's string interpolation using backticks inside of classname.

```html
<div className={`some other classes${completed ? " strike-through" : ""}`} />
```

Comment: Hey @Ryan, or anyone, how would I refer to `completed` when it is the given value of property inside an array of todo items (the total of which is in state):

 this.state = {
      id: 0,
      todos:[{id:0, completed = false}, {id:1, completed = true}, {id:2, completed = true}]

I want to refer to the completed value of a given 'todo' item, as a property.. something like completed=this.state.todos.completed , which can be referred to as something like props.completed , if that makes sense?

Comment: So in that case I would map over this.state.todos
`return this.state.todos.map((todo)=> {
 return <div className={`some other classes${todo.completed ? " strike-through" : ""}`} />
})`

Comment: Yep needed to be todo.completed! Thanks!