# Conditionally applying inline style in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I make some of canvas menu on my component in react, now it's working conditionally. So I have a state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isToggleOn: false});
}

toggleMenu() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
}
```

I want to make my body css `overflow:hidden` when my `isToggleOn` state is **true** and when it's **false** I want to delete `overflow:hidden` from **body**. How can that be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook where you check if `isToggleOn` changed in the state and update the body `overflow` style if it did.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.state.isToggleOn !== prevState.isToggleOn) {
    document.body.style.overflow = this.state.isToggleOn ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any benefit in putting that logic in CDU instead of in `toggleMenu`?

Comment: @giorgim OP is also toggling the state in CDM, so I thought it was the most straight-forward solution given that the state was updated in more than one place.