# React.js - State doesn't update when function is called in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mount, setstate, intersection-observer

I'm having an issue with changing the state of a label in a tab when I do scroll on the page. I don't know if componentDidMount() is responsible for it, but I've tried a lot of things and I just can't reach the solution. Here is the demo representing all my problems:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/clever-babbage-bzlbe?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

If you notice, the shadow loses the transition on the second time you do scroll down, but if you remove the `this.setState`'s, it will be perfect. How this can be possible to solve?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] _inside_ your question.

Comment: Avoid DOM manipulations like `document.querySelector("#nav-container")` and instead [use React to change classes, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30533171/1218980)

Comment: There's also a NPM module that wraps the `IntersectionObserver` for React, namely: [_react-intersection-observer_](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using `this.setState.scrolled` instead of `this.state.scrolled` and you were assigning `true` to it instead of checking

```
(this.state.scrolled == true ? (
              "THIS NEEDS TO CHANGE"
            ) : (
              <Box
                fontFamily="Nunito"
                fontSize={18}
                fontWeight={700}
                color="text.secondary"
                className="text-uppercase pr-4"
              >
                TO THIS
              </Box>
            ))
```

Doing this should fix your code.

Comment: Hi @kooskoos ! Thanks all of it worked out! But I still have problems with the shadow, do you know what can I do?

Comment: Can you explain the problem in detail? I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: If you notice, when you first do scroll there is a transition of a shadow in the tab (check the css for more details of it). But then, when you do the second, third time, there is more transition for the shadow, it appears suddenly very quick. Do you understand? (sorry I got to level up my english skills) @kooskoos

Comment: Is that why you are using `that` instead of `this` with setState, so that it keeps working?

Comment: I need the "that" to the state's work. Try to remove it and see what happens. My problem now is the shadow, I don't know why it loses the transition following the first scroll. @kooskoos

Comment: I got it, makes sense.