# How to access css class with React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to access CSS class with react.

Here is my CSS file:

```
    body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  transition: margin .25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
  padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 15rem;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }
}
```

in jQuery it is this:

```
 $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

I found in React people do like this:

```
    import React from 'react';
import './sidebar.component.css';

class SidebarWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        toggled: true,
        bgColor: 'black'
      };

      this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
    }

    toggleMenu= (e) => {
        this.setState({toggled: !this.state.toggled})
        this.setState({bgColor: 'red'})
        console.log(this.state.toggled)
        console.log(this.state.bgColor)
    }

    render() {
      let buttonClass = (this.state.toggled) ? 'true' : 'false';
      return (
        <div className={buttonClass}>

           <button id="menu-toggle" style={{backgroundColor:  this.state.bgColor  }} onClick={this.toggleMenu}>Toggle Menu</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  export default SidebarWrapper;
```

But nothing happens except for the color change. I'm thinking that the wrapper.toggle css class needs to be accessed somehow via react, but how?

I cannot do this.state {wrapper.toggle = true}

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is `wrapper`? where is it used?

Comment: Hi, <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper"> it's a sidebar which I want to collapse on button click

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)

Comment: I'm not quite sure, this looks like a more complex problem to me. Thing is I'm a beginner and this thread helped me grasp some important concepts and I probably couldn't solve the error with the one you provided. Thanks though!

Comment: Maybe even "[How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?]"(https://stackoverflow.com/q/6259982/1218980) could also help. Start slow, take the time, and good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```js
let buttonClass = (this.state.toggled) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

will either evaluate `buttonClass` to the string values of either 'true' or 'false'.

Using `<div className={buttonClass}>` will apply a class *equal to the value of* `buttonClass`, so the example you've provided will set the class of the div to one of those same 'true' or 'false' string values.

Additionally the css you've applied specifies a `#wrapper.toggled` selector which requires you to use the `wrapper` id on your div if you want to css rule to apply.

so change your render function to:

```js
render() {
      let buttonClass = (this.state.toggled) ? 'toggled' : '';
      return (
        <div id="wrapper" className={buttonClass}>

           <button id="menu-toggle" style={{backgroundColor:  this.state.bgColor  }} onClick={this.toggleMenu}>Toggle Menu</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `buttonClass` ternary operation, you are currently assigning the strings "true" or "false" to your div element's classlist based on your `this.state.toggled` boolean value.

Change this line:

```
let buttonClass = (this.state.toggled) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

To this:

```
let buttonClass = (this.state.toggled) ? 'toggled' : ''; // add "toggled" to your div classlist if "this.state.toggled" is true
```

---

Also, either remove the `wrapper` id from your div and use `.wrapper { styles }` in your css or add the id to your div beforehand when you render the div so that `#wrapper.toggled { styles }` in your css is targetting the element correctly.

Comment: @knaitas Glad I could help. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I think your have to remove # in your css replace it with .

And then import css `import styles from ''yourfilename"`

And then call that class name

Example

`<h1 className ={styles.yourclassname}> xyz </>`

Comment: That's only valid when using CSS modules which is irrelevant to OP's question.

Comment: Appreciate your help, I was trying this but with no success, another stackoverflower helped me :)