# Add Class to multiple Objects in ReactJS when clicked

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm fairly new to React and struggle to find a suitable answer to my question. I've got a list with multiple buttons (23) and want to add an .active class to every individual button that has been clicked. I am saving the buttons "value" in a a state array for later usage. Ergo, there can be multiple buttons with an active class and no buttons with the respective class.

```
class DistrictModal extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        selectedDistricts: []
    }
}

addDistrictToList = (e) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedDistricts: [...prevState.selectedDistricts, e]
    }));

}

render() {

<div className="list-group">
  <button type="button" onClick={() => this.addDistrictToList("1")} > 1. bezirk </button>
  <button type="button" onClick={() => this.addDistrictToList("2")} > 2. bezirk </button>
  <button type="button" onClick={() => this.addDistrictToList("3")} > 3. bezirk </button>
</div>

}}
```

Comment: onClick={(e) => { e.target.classList.add(".active"); this.addDistrictToList("1")}  can you try it?

Comment: This actually access the text within the button, not the button itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => this.addDistrictToList("1")}
className={this.state.selectedDistricts.includes(1) ? 'active' : ''}> 1. bezirk </button>
```

This adds the class `active`, if the list contains the value "1"

Source: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)

Comment: My bad, changed it

Comment: This seems so logical, but nothing happens when the button is pressed...

Comment: OK, I got it working changed "this.state.selectedDistricts.includes(1)" to this.state.selectedDistricts.includes("1")...thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cleaner code with React Hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const DistrictModal = () => {

const [selectedDistricts, setSelectedDistricts] = useState([])

const addDistrictToList = id => {
    setSelectedDistricts([
        ...selectedDistricts,
        id
    ])
}

const isDistrictSelected = id => {
    return selectedDistricts.indexOf(id) !== -1
}

return(
   <div className="list-group">
      <button type="button" className={isDistrictSelected(1) && 'active'} onClick={() => this.addDistrictToList(1)} > 1. bezirk </button>
      <button type="button" className={isDistrictSelected(2) && 'active'} onClick={() => this.addDistrictToList(2)} > 2. bezirk </button>
      <button type="button" className={isDistrictSelected(3) && 'active'} onClick={() => this.addDistrictToList(3)} > 3. bezirk </button>
    </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is create an array of buttons to render. Then for each index you remember if it has been clicked or not. Something approximately along the following lines (untested, I hope you get the gist, else I can further elaborate):

```
class DistrictModal extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedDistricts: [],
      buttons: [
        {title: 'bezirk'},
      ],
      clickedButtonIndices: [],
    }
  }

  addDistrictToList(i) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      selectedDistricts: [...prevState.selectedDistricts, i]
    }));
  }

  onButtonClick(e, i) {
    this.addDistrictToList(i);
    this.clickedButtonIndices.push(i);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="list-group">
        {
          this.buttons.map((button, i) => {
            const isActive = this.state.clickedButtonIndices.includes(i);
            return (
              <button key={i} type="button" onClick={(e) => this.onButtonClick(e, i)} className={isActive ? 'active' : ''}>{button.title}</button>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Maybe you'll have to do a `this.forceUpdate()` after the `this.clickedButtonIndices.push(i);`, as I don't think it will trigger a rerender.