# How to add dynamic TailwindCSS classes to DOM elements in React

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am new to TailWindCSS, I want to add enable/disable style to a Button element. How can I add disabled specific styles/class(i.e let's say I need to add "opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed") to the button conditionally?

```
    <button
          className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-400 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border-b-4 border-blue-700 hover:border-blue-500 rounded mr-3"
          disabled={!globalContext.users.length > 0}
          onClick={handleClearResultsClick}
        >
          Clear Results
    </button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)

Comment: Yes, it does Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

- You can use the new [ES6 "template strings"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
- This is a simple [React component](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) that has disabled the (-) button when counter <= 0
- [.pointer-even-none](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pointer-events/) is the tailwindCSS class that renders the disable button

  ```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <Fragment>
         {/* button Substract with styles tailwind*/}
        <button className={`p-2 ${count <= 0 ? 'opacity-50 pointer-events-none': 'bg-red-700'}`} 
                onClick={() => setCount( count - 1 )}>
                Substract
        </button>

        {/* Counter */}
        <span className="p-2">{ count }</span>

        {/* button Add whit styles tailwind*/}
        <button className="p-2 bg-green-700"
                onClick={() => setCount(count + 1 )}>
                Add
        </button>
    </Fragment>
  )
  ```

Comment: if `opacity-50` class is not used anywhere else in the project. it will not be available in compiled code. from my testing, it will not be available in compiled CSS and it will not work. let me know if there is a workaround for this. If your dynamic classes are used else where you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
classNames('foo', 'bar'); // => 'foo bar'
classNames('foo', { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': true }); // => 'foo-bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': false }); // => ''
classNames({ foo: true }, { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
classNames({ foo: true, bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'

// lots of arguments of various types
classNames('foo', { bar: true, duck: false }, 'baz', { quux: true }); // => 'foo bar baz quux'

// other falsy values are just ignored
classNames(null, false, 'bar', undefined, 0, 1, { baz: null }, ''); // => 'bar 1'
```

You can use this light weight library classname

https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

It will keep things tidy