# How can I add a class attribute to my html element through ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I want Reactjs to add a class named "hello" to my div in html.

I know I can simply do this in JavaScript by writing
`element.classList.add("hello");`

But React shows error for the keyword ".add"

how can I do this?

Comment: Your question suggests that you're really new to React and haven't gotten the hang of the fundamental difference between using an MVC-esque library like React, Vue, etc. vs. creating and manually updating elements. I suggest going through a few React tutorials to learn more about that difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot @T.J.Crowder for your advise, Yes I am new to react so I was trying to convert my vanilla JavaScript projects to react when I came across this problem. But thanks again, I really appreciate your answer and I will surely learn more of react as you suggested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)... Sometimes I feel like I'm the only one who searches for answers...

Answer (score 0):

You do this by including that class when rendering your component. So for instance, if you're doing a functional component and it returns like this:

```
return (
    <div>
        This is the content of the div
    </div>
);
```

you'd change it to:

```
return (
    <div className={someCondition ? "hello" : ""}>
        This is the content of the div
    </div>
);
```

...where `someCondition` controls whether the `div` should have the `hello` class or not.

Here's an example that adds the class when you click the `div`, removes it if you click again, etc.:

```js
const {useState, Component} = React;

function FunctionalExample() {
    const [hasClass, setHasClass] = useState(false);
    const onClick = e => setHasClass(v => !v);
    return (
        <div
            className={hasClass ? "hello" : ""}
            onClick={onClick}
        >
            Example in a functional component
        </div>
    );
}

class ClassExample extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hasClass: false
        };
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }
    onClick() {
        this.setState(({hasClass}) => ({hasClass: !hasClass}));
    }
    render() {
        const {hasClass} = this.state;
        return (
            <div
                className={hasClass ? "hello" : ""}
                onClick={this.onClick}
            >
                Example in a class component
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <FunctionalExample />
        <ClassExample />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.hello {
    color: blue;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or just className={name} so set the class directly?

Comment: @JuleWolf - If `name` is a variable, yes, or `className="hello"` for a literal value. But the OP's question was about *adding* a class, so I assume it's not there initially and then gets added as the result of some condition becoming true.