# Is it good idea in React to modify attribute values of an element through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, virtual-dom

Since React has its own copy of the DOM, what is the best way to modify an HTML element's attributes without affecting React's virtual DOM (Performance)?

Let's say I want to toggle between adding and removing an `active` class from a list of `div`s based on their visibility (Intersection Observer)

In Javascript I can just do:

```js
if (inView) {
    element.classList.add('active')
} else {
    element.classList.remove('active')
}
```

Will this affect React's virtual DOM? If yes can you please suggest the better way to do it?

Comment: Manipulating the DOM within React is generally and anti-pattern. Most times it still works though.. The recommended way would be to use a state variable that serves as the toggle for the class, and then use that toggle to determine what classes a tag should have when rendering your JSX.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)