# React change CSS with input

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to know how to change the CSS with an input, for example with data from 'Open Weather'. I have already coded a website with just javascript and now I wanna try to learn React but I don't get how to do it.
For example with javascript I can easily change the name of the class.

```
 if( description.indexOf('rain') > 0 ) {
    document.body.className = 'rainy';
  } else if( description.indexOf('cloud') > 0 ) {
    document.body.className = 'cloudy';
  } else if( description.indexOf('sunny') > 0 ) {
    document.body.className = 'sunny';
  } else {
    document.body.className = 'clear';
  }
```

Maybe someone can help me

Comment: I think your question does not fit in SO rules. I suggest you watch some videos and read the documentations. Happy hacking!

Comment: @ilkerkaran maybe it would be more helpful if you developed on which SO rules the question violates? except for the fact it has been asked before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this question [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)

```js
<div className={description.indexOf('rain') > 0 ? 'rainy' :  description.indexOf('cloud') > 0 ? 'cloudy' : ....)}>
```

or using [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) for a more readable approach

```js
let myWeatherClasses = classNames(
  {
    'rainy': description.indexOf('rain') > 0,
    'cloudy': description.indexOf('cloud') > 0,
    ...
  }
);
```