# How can I remove a CSS class based on condition

Tags: css, reactjs

Hi I am writing a react code for a button. Here is the code:

```
    <Button
    block={true}
    className={`sc-pc-action-button ${className}`.trim()}
    disabled={disabled}
    onClick={onClick}
  > Click me
      </Button>
```

There is a condition in which I dont need this sc-pc-action-button css.

Now this class sc-pc-action-button is hardcoded.

How can I write a CSS which tells me to ignore the contents of sc-pc-action-button and take fresh CSS I am giving.

I need a CSS solution to remove the properties. I don't need JS Solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)

Comment: sc-pc-action-button should be optional.

Comment: Make a ternary inside like:  {(condition ? 'sc-pc-action-button ' : "") + className }

Comment: adding to 
@ΚωνσταντινοςΧαφης if you don't have else statement then you can use `&&`

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
  block={true}
  className={`${someCondition ? "sc-pc-action-button" : ""} ${className}`.trim()}
  disabled={disabled}
  onClick={onClick}
> Click me
</Button>
```