# Change classname dynamically in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change a class name dynamically in react.

I am importing the classes from a related css file like this:

```
import classes from "./Board.module.css";
```

And in my Board component, I want to return a classname based on something I generate.

It can be "card" "card activate " "card disable", and I have 3 classes in my css file

```
.card {
    do card something
}

.card.activate {
    do card  activate something
}

.card.disable {
    do card disable something
}
```

How can I do it because concatenating doesn't seem to be working

**Edit**: I am trying to to this:

```
import  "./Board.module.css"

const Card = (props) => {
  const itemClass =
    "card" + (props.item.stat ? " active " + props.item.stat : "");
  return (
    <div className={itemClass} onClick={() => props.clickHandler(props.id)}>
      <label>{props.item.content}</label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

and the CSS is :

```
.card.wrong{
    background-color: red;

}
.card.correct{
    background-color: green;
}
.card.active{
    transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

I am doing so that every time I click a card, I change its class name to active and something and based on that I do a color but the class is undefined so I don't know what to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking the element in inspect mode to see whether the classes are getting attached without spaces?

Eg. `card active` is getting applied as `cardactive`.

However, here's how you'd do it :

```
// Board.module.css
.card{
do card somthing

}
.card.activate{
do card  activate somthing

}
.card.disable{
do card disable somthing

}
```

Here's a snippet of the component which uses the classes dynamically.
A *dummy* condition is used to simulate the **truthy/falsy** behavior that changes the class. Replace this using your custom logic.

Using **string literals** you can dynamically toggle between the classes as shown below:

```
import "./Board.module.css";

const MyComponent = () => {
const [condtion, setCondition] = useState(false); // this is the condition that toggles the class
return (
<>
 <span className={`card ${condition ? 'activate' : 'disable'}`}>Hello world</span>
</>
```

Note: the `activate` and `disable` class-Names are strings and not variables.