# toggle() isnt't working like it suppose to be

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

When I click the hamburger menu button I want both `.menu-btn` `.menu-mob` the menu button and the navigation menu the have to  `is-active` class and `.sqr` to have the class `.hidden` when the other two are active. That's why I used toggle() to toggle all these classes, but for some reason it is not working.

[Link to all code in repo](https://github.com/IssamAth/loopstudios-landing-page/tree/master/src/components/nav)

**Note that I'm using react and tailwind and some vanilla css**

```
const showNav = () => {
    const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn')
    const navbar = document.querySelector('.menumob')
    const sqr = document.querySelector('.sqr')

    menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      menuBtn.classList.toggle('is-active')
      navbar.classList.toggle('is-active')
      sqr.classList.toggle('hidden')
    })
```

```
 <button class="menu-btn hamburger  absolute top-0 right-0 md:hidden" onClick={showNav()}>
            <div class="bar"></div>
 </button>
```

```
 .hamburger.is-active::before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 6px);
 }

 .hamburger.is-active::after {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-9px, -8px);
 }

 .hamburger.is-active .bar {
    opacity: 0;
 }


 .menumob {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    transition: 0.4s;
 }

 .menumob.is-active {
    left:0;
 }
```

Comment: If you click the hamburger menu twice, does it work?

Comment: @nevada_scout yes it but i does not go as I want it to. the menu suppose to be displayed and at the same time the element with the class sqr should be hidden.

Comment: If you're using react why are you manually adding click listeners? (and apparently never cleaning them up)

Comment: @pilchard yeah, it's because I'm new to react. Still making so many mistakes :')

Comment: duplicate: [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are using React you should be leveraging React's DOM handling rather than manually manipulating it yourself. For your specific situation all you need is a single boolean state storing whether the menu is active or not and then using that variable you can conditionally include the relevant styles, or even conditionally render elements instead of hiding them.

```
const Nav = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleNav = () => {
    setIsActive(isActive => !isActive);
  };

  return (
    <nav className='flex flex-col justify-center h-screen md:h-screen md:mb-36 max-md:relative'>
      {/* MOBILE MENU */}
      <div
        className={'menumob container flex flex-col justify-center bg-black text-white h-screen w-screen md:hidden'
          + (isActive
            ? ' is-active'
            : '')}
      >
      </div>

      {/* Humberguer Menu */}
      <button
        className={'menu-btn hamburger  absolute top-0 right-0 md:hidden'
          + (isActive
            ? ' is-active'
            : '')}
        onClick={() => showNav()}
      >
        <div class='bar'></div>
      </button>

      {/* Imerses experiences */}
      {/* conditionall rendering with AND short-circuit */}
      {!isActive
        && (
          <div className='sqr container mx-auto my-0 top-1/2 mt-10 xl:px-56 max-md:absolute max-md:top-1/3'>
          </div>
        )}
    </nav>
  );
};
```

see related question: [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)

and the documentation:

- [React: Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)
- [React: useState](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to set up an event listener inside an `onclick` event. Every time you click, a new listener will be created causing the code to fire multiple times on each click.

In your code, the first time you click the event listener will be created but the code inside the listener won't run. The second time you click, the code inside the listener should run, but another listener will be created. The third time you click, the code inside the listener will run twice (toggling the class twice), and adding another listener. (And repeat for each click.)

The event listener is not needed at all, because the `showNav` function only runs when the hamburger menu item is clicked - because of `onClick={showNav()}` in the HTML. Try changing the code to this and see if it works:

```
const showNav = () => {
  const menuBtns = document.querySelector('.menu-btn')
  const navbars = document.querySelector('.menumob')
  const sqrs = document.querySelector('.sqr')

  menuBtn.classList.toggle('is-active')
  navbar.classList.toggle('is-active')
  sqr.classList.toggle('hidden')
};
```

Also, note that `document.querySelector` returns only the first matching element, so if you have more than one element with the class `.menu-btn`, `.menumob` or `.sqr` then not all of them will be updated.

Comment: after I tried your answer, the mobile menu no longer shows up, this time whenever I click only the button that works but nothing else.

Comment: update : I think it's started working after I have added your code and also changed ```onClick={showNav()}```  to  ```onClick={() => showNav()}```