# How to conditionally add/remove classes with TailwindCSS and React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I have an expression that looks for form errors and appends a div if once bubbles up:

```
{touched && normalizedError && (
      <div className="visible alert-error text-xs text-red-500" role="alert">
        {normalizedError}
      </div>
    )}
```

I'd like to refactor this and always display the div beneath my input elements but use the `invisble` class to hide them from the user unless an error is returned—in which case I'd conditional add the `visible` class.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Js conditionally applying class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533171/react-js-conditionally-applying-class-attributes)

Comment: [`clsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish what you want, the easiest would be to add the conditional in the className itself

```
<div className={`alert-error text-xs text-red-500 ${touched && normalizedError ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}`}  role="alert">
  {normalizedError}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways of getting this done.

#### 1.Inline inside the class

```
<div className={`... ${touched && normalizedError ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}`}>
  {normalizedError}
</div>
```

#### 2. Using a variable

```
let dependentClass = touched && normalizedError ? 'visible' : 'invisible';

className={`... ${dependentClass }`}
```

#### 3. Using [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx)

```
<div className={clsx('...',`${touched && normalizedError ? 'visible' : 'invisible'}`)}>
  {normalizedError}
</div>
```