# Syncing React's useEffect with document.querySelector()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, queryselector

I have different groups of items. When the user selects a group, the list of items updates and I then want to add a class to all the items in the selected group.

I'm trying to use useEffect to render the items and add a class to them. The problem is that querySelector is finding all items of the previous groupId, not the one being selected. I thought useEffect runs after the render. So shouldn't the items in the selected group render, then run querySelector?

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work?

```
export const Component = (props: { groupId: number; }) => {
  const { groupId } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    let items: any;
    items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
    for (let item of items) {
      item.classList.add('new-class');
    }
  }, [groupId]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index} className='item'>{item.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly modifying the DOM like that is anti-React. You're straying from a proper data-driven approach and making more work for yourself (and future devs). See [Conditionally applying class attributes in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30533171/1264804).

You'll either want to conditionally apply your class (without useEffect) or update the styles of the element when the ID value changes (*with* useEffect).

It's not clear what your business logic is, so I can't be more specific. It appears that you're marking all items as new whenever the group ID changes. Here's a guess at what might work:

```
  const [idUpdated, setIdUpdated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIdUpdated(true);
  }, [groupId]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index} 
            className={'item' + idUpdated ? ' new-class' : ''}>{item.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
```