# how to filter array data in javascript on boolean condition?

Tags: arrays

I want to filter data of array whose boolean value is true.

Below image is my code:

[image: arraystrong text]

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: @Bharat Aggarwal Welcome to StackOverflow. Provide minimal code-snippet, the issue that you are facing and expected output. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript .filter() true booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016773/javascript-filter-true-booleans)

Comment: it would better you if add code [JSON] in the question itselft

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
return this.carServices.filter(item => item.BooleanField === true);
```