# How to remove empty key from object in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, filter

I have an JSONarray which looks like this,

```
        {
        "TotalMemory": [{
            "key": "TotalMemory",
            "values": [
                [118, 10]
            ]
        }],
        "Freememory": [{
            "key": "Freememory",
            "values": [
                [121, 10]
            ]
        }],
        "BufferSize": [{
            "key": "BufferSize",
            "values": [
                [123, 10]
            ]
        }],
        "TotalSwapMemory": [{
            "key": "TotalSwapMemory",
            "values": [
                [125, 10]
            ]
        }],
        "UsedSwapMemory": [{
            "key": "UsedSwapMemory",
            "values": [
                [127, 10]
            ]
        }],
        "FeeSwapMemory": [{
            "key": "FeeSwapMemory",
            "values": [
                [129, 10]
            ]
        }],
        "": [{
            "key": "",
            "values": []
        }]
    }
```

i need to remove the last item which is empty there. I have followed [Remove empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript) , but this does not work.

```
$scope.displayData  = $scope.displayData.filter(function() { return true; });
console.log(angular.toJson($scope.displayData));
```

Comment: why not use lodash or underscore, `_.reject` function

Comment: cant we directly remove using javascript?

Comment: is it a JSONArray or JSONObject ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), like so

```
Object.keys($scope.displayData).forEach(function(key) {
    if (!key) {
        delete $scope.displayData[key];
    }
});
```

`$scope.displayData` is `Object`, [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is Array method, in [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) there is no `.filter` method

Answer (score 2):

Your structure is not an `Array`, it is an `Object` with keys (properties) and values.

To remove the empty item, you can simply use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

`delete $scope.displayData[""];`

This will not error if `$scope.displayData[""]` does not exist.