# Split string with tags using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to split this kind of texts in the following manner:

```
"string1<%string2%>string3"   => [string1, <%string2%>, string3]
"string1<%string2%><%string3%>"   => [string1, <%string2%>, <%string3%>]
```

How can this be done with regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```js
alert("string1<%string2%><%string3%>".split(/(<%.*?%>)/).filter(Boolean));
```

The `(<%.*?%>)` regex matches `<%...%>`-like entities, and captures them so that they are preserved in the resulting array. An alternative regex can also be `(<%(?!%>).*?%>)`.

With [`.filter(Boolean)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443800/3832970) you will be able to get rid of any empty array elements.

In case there are no spaces inside `<%...%>`, you can use `(<%\S+%>)` regex.

Comment: Yes, this often pops up with `split`, but fortunately, there is `filter(Boolean)`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `<` and `>` does not appear in the text outside `<%` and `%>`, you can use match instead:

```
"string1<%string2%><%string3%>string4".match(/[^<>]+|<%.*?%>/g)
>>> ["string1", "<%string2%>", "<%string3%>", "string4"]
```

Comment: I would like to stress the *Assuming* part. OP does not precise the type of input, but it is common knowledge `>` is sometimes not entitized in XML and HTML.

Comment: @stribizhev Can't be helped. Meddling with HTML or XML like structure with regex without knowing the grammar is like swinging a sword in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var re = /(<%[^%]*%>)/;
var m = "string1<%string2%><%string3%>".split(re).filter(Boolean);
//=> ["string1", "<%string2%>", "<%string3%>"]

var m = "string1<%string2%>string3".split(re).filter(Boolean);
//=> ["string1", "<%string2%>", "string3"]
```