# filter empty values in select input before sending to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove empty values from Java script array data. Here I am using this code to get data from select box options. Please help me how to avoid empty elements before sending to server.

Javascript Code

```
var attributevalues = new Array();
        $('select[name=attributevalue]').each(function(){
           attributevalues.push($(this).val());
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @Script47 can you tell me how to implement that for my code. I am new to javascript

Comment: check first if the value is not empty `var attributevalues = [];
$('select[name=attributevalue]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length) attributevalues.push($(this).val());
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for that before pushing, like this:

```
var attributevalues = new Array();

$('select[name=attributevalue]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val())
        attributevalues.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Other shortcut method available with `jQuery` is `grep`. Using that code will be like below -

```
attributevalues = $.grep(attributevalues,function(value){ return value });
```

give it a try

Answer (score 0):

```
var trim = function ( ary ) { // remove empty elements
    return ary.filter(function (item) {
        return !!item;
    });
};
```