# Get first element in array with index not starting from 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm using a javascript library which returns arrays not starting from zero like starting from 26 or 1500, what i want to do is a method to get the first element in that array regardless of the index number starting with 0 or any other number.

Are they any method to do this in javascript ?

Comment: What is that `javascript` library? what have you tried so far? examples of your code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information below is generally useful, but for the problem the OP listed, [Nina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37991354/157247) is by far a better solution.

---

Those are called *sparse* arrays and they're one of the few situations where you may want to use `for-in` on an array.

Remember that arrays are objects in JavaScript, and array entries are properties keyed by names (array indexes) that meet [certain criteria](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4). So we can use the features that let us discover the properties on an object to find the indexes on your sparse array.

`for-in` example:

```
for (var n in theArray) {
    if (theArray.hasOwnProperty(n) && isArrayIndex(n)) {
        // Use theArray[n]
    }
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) shows how you can determine that `n` is an array index as opposed to being some other property. A *very technical definition* would be

```
function isArrayIndex(n) {
    return /^0$|^[1-9]\d*$/.test(n) &&
           n <= 4294967294;
}
```

...but a definition that's good enough for most of us would be

```
function isArrayIndex(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseInt(n, 10));
}
```

Similarly, you can use `Object.keys`; since it only looks at *own* enumerable properties, you don't need the `hasOwnProperty` check:

```
Object.keys(theArray).forEach(function(n) {
    if (isArrayIndex(n)) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Note that **officially**, neither of those is in any particular order, not even in ES2015 ("ES6"). So in **theory**, you could see the indexes out of numeric order. In the real world, I've never seen an even vaguely-modern JavaScript engine that returned array indexes out of order. They're not *required* to, but every one I've tried does.

So officially, you would need to get a full list and then find the minimum value in it:

```
var min = Object.keys(theArray).reduce(function(min, n) {
    var i = parseInt(n, 10);
    return isNaN(i) || (min !== undefined && min > i) ? min : i;
}, undefined);
```

That'll given you `undefined` if the array is empty, or the min index if it isn't. But if you want to make the assumption you'll get the keys in numeric order:

```
// Makes an assumption that may not be true
var min = +Object.keys(theArray).filter(isArrayIndex)[0];
```

If you're using a JavaScript engine that's entirely up-to-date, you can rely on the order returned by [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.getownpropertynames), which **is** required to list the array indexes in order.

```
var min = +Object.getOwnPropertyNames(theArray).filter(isArrayIndex)[0];
```

Comment: @azelix: You're very welcome, but take a look at [Nina's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37991354/157247) -- she has a **much** better way to get the first index.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). You get the first nonsparse element and the index. The iteration stops immediately if you return `true` in the callback:

```js
var a = [, , 22, 33],
    value,
    index;

a.some(function (v, i) {
    value = v;
    index = i;
    return true;
});

console.log(index, value);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, it works, btw with `undefined` values as well.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to use a filter function on the array to get back a normalised array.

```
var fullArray = array.filter(function(n){
    return n != undefined;
});
fullArray[0]
```

The answers here may help you decide [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: you lose the index, if that is important.

Comment: Actually, that filters out two completely different things: *Missing* entries (because `filter` doesn't visit those at all), and entries that are present but have the value `undefined`. If you just want to filter out *missing* entries, `var fullArray = array.filter(function() { return true; });`

Answer (score 1):

I guess one alternative to `Array.prototype.some()` is the `Array.prototype.findIndex()` method. These are much faster than filter alone and will keep your array and indices untouched.

```js
var arr = new Array(1000),
     fi = -1;
arr[777] = 1453; // now we have a nice sparse array
fi = arr.findIndex(f => f !== void 0); // void 0 is the perfect undefined
console.log(fi);
console.log(arr[fi]);
```

Comment: This requires a **lot** more calls to the callback than Nina's `Array#some` (because `findIndex` visits sparse elements), and your condition filters out entries that are present but have the value `undefined`, not just missing entries.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder : "because findIndex visits sparse elements" No it does not and it would be very pointless if it did. Please read first paragraph. https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Description

Comment: Do you *really* think I'd say that if I weren't sure? If I hadn't checked? I checked [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.findindex) and proved it experimentally before commenting. https://jsfiddle.net/hwk7fuah/ I'm sorry MDN mislead you, I hate when that happens, but you might have taken the time to give it a quick test before being snarky. :-) MDN is extremely good most of the time, but it *is* community-edited and sometimes clangers like that one make their way in. I've fixed it.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder : OK sorry for sounding snarly. Apologies. But there is this; `a = new Array(1000)` doesn't produce any indices and `a[777] = 9` produces only "1" index key (property of array object) as 777. Check with a for in loop you will get only one property. So no array method including `findIndex` can not visit not existing properties even if they wanted to. We need fill() first.  But most importantly findIndex & indexOf are two of the best optimized tools in JS. Please check a comparison of findIndex and some on 1M items sparse array in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hwk7fuah/2/

Comment: *"Check with a for in loop you will get only one property."* Yes, I know how sparse arrays work. *"So no array method including findIndex can not visit not existing properties even if they wanted to."* Sure they can, and many do: Look at `Array#some`, it doesn't visit nonexistant entries. Neither does `forEach`. Or `filter`. Or `map`. `find` and `findIndex` are exceptions to the general rule.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: As per the `undefined` comment. I am using `void 0` for some reason and it is `void 0 === "undefined" // false`so if OP had "undefined" in his array as a first non sparse element he will still get it. I doubt OP will be interested in this because he phrases his question such that we understand he is not interested in the undefined items while with a slight possibility he might with "undefined" items. This was my understanding.

Comment: please try `ar[666] = undefined;`.

Comment: @Nina Scholz: Sorry i was out drinking lots of beer... just got back home an tested `arr[666] = undefined` or `var a; arr[666] = a;` and it won't find them as expected. Just couldn't get the point...

Comment: the point is, if you take your assingment of `arr[777] = 1453;` and my wanted `ar[666] = undefined;`  and perform your find index, you won't get 666/undefined, but 777/1453. but 666/undefined is the first nonsparse item.

Comment: @Nina Scholz yes true. I am not just passing the sparse slots but i am passing the ones which are `undefined` (including the sparse ones "except" the ones which are `"undefined"`). Why in the world the OP would like to have an `undefined` item as a first entry... That's my understanding from the question. If he does... well then i will do my check with the `in` operator and the world peace would be set again.

Comment: *and the world peace would be set again* calm down.

Comment: @Nina Scholz just joking...i am very happy tonight. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115446/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-redu).

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = [0,1,2]
```

// using destructuring to get the first element

```
let [first] = arr
```

// plus: using destructuring to get the last element

```
let [first] = [...arr].reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

With this piece of code you can find first assigned value index and then get the value from your array:

```js
var a = [, , 22, 33];
var value = a.find((v, i) => i in a);
console.log(value);
/* ---------------------------------------------- */
var i = 0
while (!(i in a) && i < a.length) i++; // If i === a.length then the array is emtpy
console.info(i, a[i]);
```

First implementation uses `Array.prototype.find` which makes less variable usage so this is cleaner but to find the index you should call `indexOf` over the array.

But the second one is a little bit old fashioned but give the chance of having index without extra efforts.

---

BTW [Nina's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37991354/3078890) seems better. (can make it shorter?)