# remove empty object value from reactive form valueChanges

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have reactive form in angular application. I subscribe to it with 
**valueChanges** and before get the result of **subscribe** method, want to filter this object with rxjs **filter** or some similar method to get only not empty feald of form. How can I solve this?

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
     debounceTime(500),
     filter(formObj => {
     // code that remove empty object values
     })
).subscribe(val => {
  // val example `{fullName: "name", dateOfBirthday: "", phoneNumber: "", fullAddress: ""}`       
});
```

Comment: refer this one may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521648/remove-empty-objects-from-array

Comment: so where's the problem? Instead of `filter()` you can use `map()` and change `formObj` to whatever you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had created a Stackblitz [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-empty-valuechanges) for your reference

You can somehow implement it like this:

```
filterEmptyFields(data: any): any {    // Filter any fields that aren't empty & store in a new object - To be passed on the Pipe map's caller
    let fields = {};
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key =>  data[key] != '' ? fields[key] = data[key] : key);

    return fields;   
}

trackEmptyFields(): void {
    this.form
      .valueChanges
      .pipe(map(this.filterEmptyFields))
      .subscribe(fields => console.log(fields));    
}
```

---

**Output from the Stackblitz [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-empty-valuechanges)**

[image]

Comment: Or you can use ' Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => (!data[key]) && delete data[key]);'
if your values can be empty or 'null' or 'undefined'