# remove array object from nested array if element is undefined using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Raw array

```
myArr = [
{name:'abcd',values:[undefined,{quarter: "Q2-2016", koordinaten: 119},{quarter: "Q3-2016", koordinaten: 129},undefined]},
{name:'abcd',values:[undefined,undefined,{quarter: "Q4-2016", koordinaten: 19},undefined]}
]
```

Expected array,

```
 myArr = [
        {name:'abcd',values:[{quarter: "Q2-2016", koordinaten: 119},{quarter: "Q3-2016", koordinaten: 129}},
        {name:'abcd',values:[{quarter: "Q4-2016", koordinaten: 19}]}
        ]
```

i want to remove undefined element with index  in result array,

Comment: `{undefined}` does not work. please add real code to the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz Somehow its working in chrome console.

Comment: right, but if you have control over the construction of an object, you could omit using `undefined` as key/value.

Comment: i don't have any control on construction of array - please suggest me answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try `map` and `filter`

```
myArr.map( s => (s.values = s.values.filter( p => JSON.stringify(p) != "{}" ), s ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var myArr = [
{name:'abcd',values:[{undefined},{quarter: "Q2-2016", koordinaten: 119},
{quarter: "Q3-2016", koordinaten: 129},{undefined}]},
{name:'abcd',values:[{undefined},{undefined},{quarter: "Q4-2016", koordinaten: 19},{undefined}]}
];

var output = myArr.map(s => (s.values = s.values.filter(p => JSON.stringify(p) != "{}"), s));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, you basically need to remove all the undefined values by looping through them.

```js
myArr = [
{name:'abcd',values:[undefined,{quarter: "Q2-2016", koordinaten: 119},{quarter: "Q3-2016", koordinaten: 129},undefined]},
{name:'abcd',values:[undefined,undefined,{quarter: "Q4-2016", koordinaten: 19},undefined]}
]

myArr.forEach(arrItem => {
 arrItem.values = arrItem.values.filter(x => !!x);
});

console.log(myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values (like `undefined`) with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) as callback.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'abcd', values: [undefined, { quarter: "Q2-2016", koordinaten: 119 }, { quarter: "Q3-2016", koordinaten: 129 }, undefined] }, { name: 'abcd', values: [undefined, undefined, { quarter: "Q4-2016", koordinaten: 19 }, undefined] }];

array.forEach(function (o) {
    o.values = o.values.filter(Boolean);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use, underscore for such kind of tasks.

[Compact](http://underscorejs.org/#compact) method

```js
myArr = [{
  name: 'abcd',
  values: [undefined, {
    quarter: "Q2-2016",
    koordinaten: 119
  }, {
    quarter: "Q3-2016",
    koordinaten: 129
  }, undefined]
}, {
  name: 'abcd',
  values: [undefined, undefined, {
    quarter: "Q4-2016",
    koordinaten: 19
  }, undefined]
}]

// Cleansed Array
myArr = myArr.map(function(arrItem) {
  arrItem.values = _.compact(arrItem.values);
  return arrItem
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```