# Javascript apply .join() to item in object collection only if not undefined/empty/null?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I have a collection of objects, whose values I'm storing in variable

```
var filters = {
    BeginDate: $("#BeginDateRange").val(),
    EndDate: $("#EndDateRange").val(),
    ListOfCodes: $("#ListOfCodes").val(),
    //ListOfCodes: $("#ListOfCodes").val().join(),
    ...
}
```

Based on where I use the collection, some of its objects remain 'undefined', and it is intended.

ListOfCodes above is an array of string values, and I want to pass it to the binder as a single comma-separated string (e.g ["1"], ["2"] -> "1,2")

I was able to make a use of .join(), and it worked successfully. However, I found later that the code will crash if the .join() does not have a value to join.

**Is there a way to apply .join() INSIDE the collection to the variable ONLY if it has value?** Something like

```
var filters = {
    BeginDate: $("#BeginDateRange").val(),
    EndDate: $("#EndDateRange").val(),
    ListOfCodes: if( $("#ListOfCodes").val() )
                     {$("#ListOfCodes").val().join()} 
                  else
                      {$("#ListOfCodes").val()}    //value remains undefined
    ,
    ...
}
```

EDIT: I ask about the possibility of applying .join() method inside the collection, not checking for empty values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Assign to variables then test with an if statement? `if (variable == null){  // your code here. }`

Comment: ListOfCodes: $("#ListOfCodes").val().join() || undefined

Comment: @I.R.R. My question is if I can do it INSIDE the collection.

Comment: @Cruiser I'm testing your suggestion for both cases, I'll let you know once I get the results.

Comment: it's possible you won't be able to call join() after .val(), however. it's just a suggestion on how you can test for a value or assign it to undefined

Comment: @Cruiser It didn't work, unable to get property join of undefined or null reference.

Comment: is there a reason you can't just test the var before you use join() on it?

Comment: What about a ternary statement? `ListOfCodes: ($("#ListOfCodes").val()) ? $("#ListOfCodes").val().join() : null`

Comment: @ReyHaynes If you want some free points, write it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @ReyHaynes even easier if you just do something like `ListOfCodes: ($("#ListOfCodes").val() || "").join()`, so you get an empty string as default.

Comment: @vlaz does an empty string have a `join()` method?

Comment: @vlaz That would have to be an empty array, `[]`

Comment: @Herohtar You're right, sorry. I was just in a hurry, and made a mistake. My main point was to use `||`  instead of terniary as it's shorter and you can get a default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just moving this as an answer.

What about a ternary statement?

`ListOfCodes: ($("#ListOfCodes").val()) ? $("#ListOfCodes").val().join() : null`

Comment: Accepted. Thanks a lot!