# Filter [empty] array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm deleting some array object in traditional way: `delete subDirectories[index]`. So, just after that this object is changing to `[empty]` one. Now, how to filter that, `undefined, bool, NaN` nothing works. I'm working with Vue.js and this contains an `vuex` action. Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Are you sure this is javascript?

Comment: @keithlee96 I've added the console log screen.

Comment: @GaurangDave tried this, and just like above, none of them doesn't work :(

Comment: @Lukas Can you share the JS code (operation you are performing)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to delete all null, undefined, (or any false-like) values in an array, you can just do:

```
var arr = [1,3,5, null, False];
var res = arr.filter(val=>val);
console.log(res); // [1,3,5]
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly remove null and undefined:

```
var res = arr.filter(val => (val!==undefined) && (val!==null));
console.log(res); // [1,3,5]
```

Comment: In this case; because element was removed with `delete` you have a value in the array called `empty`. If the value is `empty` the function in filter isn't called so you can do this: `arr.filter(x=>true);` Try this in console:`arr = [1,2,3];delete arr[1];arr.filter(x=>true);`

Comment: @HMR Huh, that works. That's way more elegant than my solution. I had no idea that empty was a thing in Javascript Arrays. So are empty cells always ignored by all array functions (filter, map, etc)? Is there a difference between empty and undefined?

Comment: Empty is a special value, the array is `empty x 10) when doing `new Array(10)` Map isn't called when you do: `new Array(10).map(_=>console.log("hi"))` It's also not called when you delete: `var arr = [1,2,3];delete arr[0];arr.map(x=>{ console.log(x);return x; })` but the array returned still has a length of 3 and the empty item is still there. I try to avoid `delete` and use `new Array` like this: `Array.from(new Array(10),(x,index)=>index)`