# Splicing empty array on Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I am trying to remove the empty array elements (from a *csv* file) by using the `splice()` function.

The array elements are stored inside `csv.data`:

```
csv.data.forEach(function(item,index) {
    if (item.length < 2) { // don't want anything less than two
        csv.data.splice(index,1); 
        }
    });
```

This works, but it still returns me two empty arrays (lines) in the *csv* file, originally, there are six empty lines, but it skips the two empty lines.

Am I doing anything wrong?

This is the `csv.data`

```
[
 [
  "1212",
  "okay",
  ""
 ],
 [
  ""
 ],
 [
  ""
 ],
 [
  ""
 ],
 [
  ""
 ],
 [
  ""
 ],
 [
  ""
 ]
]
```

Expected

```
[
 [
  "1212",
  "okay",
  ""
 ],
]
```

Comment: iterating while splicing ... not a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @NinaScholz it absolutely correct. Any type of modifying of location of elements of an array, whether moving, adding, or removing, in a forEach could have undesired consequences. You would be better using a `for` loop and adding logic to keep track of where you were (but only as a fun way to understand the logic and why it breaks). But, that's also not the best solution here. I just thought I would reiterate why these modifications are not recommended in a forEach.

Comment: What is the content of `csv.data` ?

Comment: posted @Weedoze Answer updated

Comment: That update is not that helpful, it looks now like an array of array.  Could you try doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(csv.data, null, "  "))` and copy post that.

Comment: @Keith updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the array from the end and splice without colliding with the index.

```js
var array = [["1212", "okay", ""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""]],
    i = array.length;
    
while (i--) {
    if (array[i].length < 2) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks, Nina Scholz to the rescue !

Answer (score 6):

It's not a good idea to use splice inside the loop. You can miss some indexes. 
You can use `filter` function instead of `forEach`

```js
var csv = { data: [["1212", "okay", ""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""]] };

csv.data = csv.data.filter(items => items.length > 1);

console.log(csv.data);
```

Comment: Already tried this, this somehow returns true and false for `csv.data`

Comment: It will return an array with same data, but filtered., which is in the `csv.data`.

Comment: This returns `false` I already tried doing this. Maybe has to do something with `csv.data` being an object

Comment: Please update the question and add an example of `csv.data` as this answer is 100% correct, for the question as it currently stands.

Comment: Hard to tell what your update is, but it looks like an array of arrays..  So just do a map followed by a filter.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan can you check my updated question? This answer won't work I guess

Comment: @zuif If you run this answer on the array from the updated question you get an array with a single array element in it: `[["121", "okay", ""]]`

Comment: `[
 [
  "1212",
  "okay",
  ""
 ],
 [
  ""
 ],
 [
  ""
 ],
 [
  ""
 ],
 [
  ""
 ],
 [
  ""
 ],
 [
  ""
 ]
]`

Comment: I've added the array and a code snippet, to show this working exactly as described.

Comment: @Archer Thanks.

Comment: Guys, this code is perfectly legit. But for my context doesn't work, array filter just returns `false` so my array is just false. Nina Scholz's answer below worked for me, so I am going to accept that.

Comment: @zuif - you're 100% wrong.  This code works and if you just click a simple button then you'd see it.  If this answer is in any way incorrect then it's because you have failed to describe the problem.

Comment: @Archer That's correct. And that's what I am saying. This code is 100% correct, but in my `context` didn't worked. That being said, I am 100% incapable of describing my `context`, so it's 100% my mistake

Comment: @zuif There is no context in which `filter` returns false unless you are doing something horribly wrong and overwriting the method on the array prototype.

Answer (score 1):

If you also wanted to remove empty elements from the top array, you could do another filter.

eg.

```js
const a = [ [ "1212", "okay", "" ], [ "" ], [ "" ], [ "" ], [ "" ], [ "" ], [ "" ] ];

const ret1 = a.map((b) => b.filter((f) => f));
console.log(ret1);

//if you also want to remove empty elements from top array.
const ret2 = ret1.filter((f) => f.length);
console.log(ret2);
```