# replacing empty with zero values in array

Tags: javascript

i have an array as , i need to remove the empty values and replace it with zeros.

i have achieved this much . when i checked the array length is 8 but it shows 2 elements only. What is the best method to replace it with zeros.

```
var a = [];

a[3] = 5

a[5] = 15

console.log(a.length) // 6

console.log(a) // [empty,empty,empty,5,empty,15] 

how can i make the output as [0,0,0,5,0,15]
```

// tried this way didn't worked

```
a.map(o => o !== null ? o : 0)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One method is to use `Array.from`, which iterates over each element from 0 to the `length` of the array (unlike `map`, which only iterates over properties that are actually on the array)

```js
var a = [];
a[3] = 5
a[5] = 15

a = Array.from(a, item => item || 0);
console.log(a);
```

If there are possibly non-zero falsey values in the array that you don't want to be replaced with 0, you can do a `typeof` check:

```js
var a = [];
a[3] = 5
a[2] = null;
a[5] = 15

a = Array.from(a, item => typeof item === 'undefined' ? 0 : item);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: ...`map` doesnt work because it only iterates over existing properties while `Array.from` iterates all properties

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to do this and set the value you want to replace with 0,'' or null

```
function replaceEmptyWith(arr,val) {
  var _arr = [];
  if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] === undefined) _arr[i] = val;
      else _arr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return _arr;
  }
  return arr;
}

var a = [];

a[3] = 5

a[5] = 15

a = replaceEmptyWith(a,0);
```

Also I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript) which may help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```js
var a = [];
a[3] = 5
a[2] = null
a[5] = 15

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {   
    if (a[i] == undefined) {
        a[i] = 0;
    }   
}
console.log(a);
```

also, You can use `Array.prototype.map`:

```
a = a.map(function(val, i) {
    return val === undefined ? 0 : val;
});
```