# Replace null values to 0 in array

Tags: javascript

I need to push 0 in users element if the array's length is less than 7.

Example: If array has 2 elements. The rest should have 0 in it's users and _id as the index number.

Please help me to acheive this

```
 const newUsers = [
    {
        _id: 1,
        users: 8
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        users: 6
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        users: 1
    },
    {
        _id: 4,
        users: 8
    },
    {
        _id: 5,
        users: 0
    },
    {
        _id: 7,
        users: 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replacing empty with zero values in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51259553/replacing-empty-with-zero-values-in-array)

Comment: What does the question have to do with the title?

Comment: I mentioned it as a help. I tried my best and asked for a suggestion. Didn't asked for your "code-writing service" anyway.

Comment: Can you please share to us the code? We can't write your code out from scratch. It is expected that you have at least written a bit of code before noticing a problem, and can't find any answers. For more information, please see [Stack Overflow's guide on _How to Ask_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (let i = newUsers.length; i < 7; i += 1) {
  newUsers.push({ _id: i + 1, users: 0 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [W3Schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp), you can use map operator to change all the users property.

```js
const newUsers = [
    {
        _id: 1,
        users: 8
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        users: 6
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        users: 1
    },
    {
        _id: 4,
        users: 8
    },
    {
        _id: 5,
        users: 8
    }
]

if (newUsers.length < 7) 
  newUsers.map(x => x.users = 0);
  
console.log(newUsers)
```