# Remove objects with empty values from array / Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
let arr = [{id:0, value: 'zero'}, 
           {id:1, value: 'one'}, 
           {id:2, value: ''}]
```

I need to remove object with empty value. What I am trying:

```
const removeEmpty = (arr) => {
let filtered = arr.filter(val => val.value != '');
return filtered;
```

};

Stuck with this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

Edit: corrected syntax

Comment: How do you invoke `removeEmpty`?

Comment: Your naming is bad practice - your parameter `arr` shadows the `arr` in the closure. You should rename the parameter, and decide whether you want to use the variable from the closure or the parameter (likely the latter, or you wouldn't need a parameter at all).

Comment: Also, it can be `arr.filter(val => val.value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, you are looking for something like this:

```js
var arr = [{id:0, value: 'zero'}, {id:1, value: 'one'}, {id:2, value: ''}];

var filteredArr = arr.filter(obj => obj.value != '')
console.log(filteredArr);
```

NOTE: Your's is not a proper array (because `Objects` inside it are invalid).

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma on the value of id and a quote for the value of the `value` property

```js
let arr = [{id:0, value: "zero"}, 
           {id:1, value: "one"}, 
           {id:2, value: ''}];
           
           
console.log(arr.filter(a => a.value != ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your arr is not correct i.e object  key value pair is not valid

```
let arr = [{id:0, value: 'zero'}, {id:1, value: 'one'},  {id:2, value: ''}];

const removeEmpty = (arr) => {
  let filtered = arr.filter(val => val.value !== ''); 
  return filtered;
}

removeEmpty(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This questions is already answered in below link, Please have a look

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)!

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful in more cases, for instance if object value is: **false**, `null`, *empty string* or `undefined`.

```
let arr = [
  {id:0, value: 'zero'}, 
  {id:1, value: 'one'}, 
  {id:2, value: ''},
  {id:3, value: false},
  {id:4, value: null},
  {id:5}
];

const filteredArr = arr.filter(obj => obj.value);  

console.log(filteredArr);
```