# How do i replace data from jquery map and add comma at the back

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to get all input values using jQuery map and separate each value data with comma.

**Code**

```js
var filterArray = $('form#FilterHiddenForm input.cuisine_filter').map(function() {
  text = $(this).val();
  return text;
}).get().join(","); //without the join it will return (,,,,), even when value is empty.
console.log(filterArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="FilterHiddenForm">
  <input type="hidden" class="cuisine_filter" value=".now" />
  <input type="hidden" class="cuisine_filter" value=".later" />
  <input type="hidden" class="cuisine_filter" value=".before" />
  <input type="hidden" class="cuisine_filter" value=".never" />
</form>
```

**Output**

> .now.later.before.never

**Expected result**

I intend making something that will look like below, separate ever value with comma.

> .now, .later, .before, .never

Comment: It already returns what you want, except for the space after the comma. Add that to the `join` argument.

Comment: Your output already has comma separators. What's wrong?

Comment: @QuentinVeron but from my code is returning commas for empty value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript) - just do `.filter(n => n).join(",")` instead of `.join(",")`.

Comment: @TylerRoper it worked for me