# Remove empty subarrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have such an object

```
var data = [[1,2,34,4,5,6],[3,34,5,3,42,4],[,,,,,],[,,,],[,,,,,],[1,1]]
```

I need to filter it and get such a result:

```
var data = [[1,2,34,4,5,6],[3,34,5,3,42,4],[1,1]]
```

I tried to do it with `array.filter()` but I can't get the right expression.

Comment: objects use curly brackets, like this: `var data = {...}`

Comment: @rpivovar arrays are objects too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `filter` and `some`

```js
let a = [[1,2,34,4,5,6],[3,34,5,3,42,4],[,,,,,],[,,,],[,,,,,],[1,1]]

let final = a.filter(val=> val.some(v => true))

console.log(final)
```

Comment: 1/2 ... The test for an empty array is not correct. It only accidentally works with the given example ... `[,,,,,].every(v => v === undefined)`. Since the given array literal by definition ***is*** an entirely sparse array (thus empty), it gets not iterated at all ... but the method `every` by definition also returns the `true` value for any empt array without running its provided callback function even once. Compare (a) `[,,,,,].every(v => {console.log(v); return (v === undefined);})` with (b) `[,,undefined,,,].every(v => {console.log(v); return (v === undefined);})` ...

Comment: 2/2 ...(a) does not log at all since it processes an entirely sparse array, but (b) does because the operated array is not entirely sparse. The test for an empty array then does fail because of the wrong condition provided with the callback function ... after all, `[,,undefined,,,]` is not an empty array. It explicitly holds an `undefined` value at index 2 ... `2 in [,,undefined,,,]` is `true`, whereas it is `false` for any other index in between 0 and 4. Thus a valid test for real array emptiness should be based on `some` ... e.g.: `function isEmptyArray(arr) {return !arr.some(o => true); }`

Comment: @PeterSeliger thanks for the info mate :), wasn't aware of it , fixed

Answer (score 2):

```
 const result = array.map(it => it.filter(_ => true)).filter(sub => sub.length)
```

First of all, remove all the empty slots from the inner arrays, then remove all arrays with length 0.

Comment: I would consider marking this one as the most helpful answer since it's approach works for both edge cases, entirely empty arrays and partially sparse ones too which will be condensed into non-sparse arrays.

Answer (score 0):

it a double filter case: ( and the shortest code ) ;)

```js
var  data = [[1,2,34,4,5,6],[3,34,5,3,42,4],[,,,,,],[,,,],[,,,,,],[1,1]]

var R = data.filter(r=>r.filter(x=>x).length)

console.log( JSON.stringify(R) )
```

Comment: You can safely remove `length > 0` part mate you can simply use `data.filter(r=>r.filter(x=>x).length)`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a more declarative example. Hope it helps:

- create a function `isArrayEmpty(arr)` that returns a boolean that is true if an array is empty. To go deeper into detecting empty values in an array (not just `falsy`) see this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript). Also see Peter's comment.
- with this function, filter `data` excluding empty subarrays.

```js
var data = [[1,2,34,4,5,6],[3,34,5,3,42,4],[,,,,,],[,,,],[,,,,,],[1,1]]

var isArrayEmpty = arr => !arr.filter(elem => true).length;

var result = data.filter(subarray => !isArrayEmpty(subarray))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: ... the implementation of `isArrayEmpty` might be reconsidered ... compare your's `isArrayEmpty([,,,undefined,,,,])` with this approach ... `function isEmptyArray(arr) {return !arr.some(o => true); }` ... and `isEmptyArray([,,,undefined,,,,])` ... see my 2 cents to @code-maniac 's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [[1],[1,2],[,2],[,,],,[]]

console.log(JSON.stringify( arr.filter(a => 0 in a) ))

console.log(JSON.stringify( arr.filter(a => Object.keys(a).length) )) // to include sparse subarrays
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be use reduce and some.

```js
const data = [[1,2,34,4,5,6],[3,34,5,3,42,4],[,,,,,],[,,,],[,,,,,],[1,1]];

const filteredData = data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  if(currentValue.some(x => x)){
    accumulator.push(currentValue);
  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(filteredData);
```